# Комментарий или ответ?

Tags: поддержка, faq, ответы, комментарии

Своей идеологией Stack Overflow существенно отличается от традиционного интернет-форума, объединяя в себе черты вики-энциклопедий, коллективных блогов, лент новостей и собственно форума. Одной из главных особенностей проекта является многократное использование решений - вопрос, описывающий проблему, публикуется однажды, получает решение в виде ответа, а затем используется многократно пользователями, приходящими из поисковых систем.

Такой формат накладывает определенные ограничения на общение в сообществе. Вопрос и ответы к нему - это главные сообщения любой темы, а комментарии носят лишь вспомогательную функцию. Это удобно для решения практических задач: вопрос - проблема, ответ - решение, комментарии - уточнения. При этом сама тема становится мини-публикацией, посвященной решению конкретной проблемы.

Если вы хотите поделиться знаниями с сообществом, но неуверенны в выборе типа сообщения, рекомендуем пользоваться следующими правилами:

- создавать в одной теме только один вопрос; если в процессе уточнения ответов возникают новые вопросы и эти вопросы достаточно объемные, то стоит задать новый вопрос;
- при необходимости уточнять сообщение, редактируя исходный вопрос или ответ, вместо добавления уточняющих комментариев;
- уточнять исходный ответ вместо создания дополнительных так, чтобы в каждой теме был только один ответ от одного автора;
- использовать правки вместо добавления комментария при уточнении вопроса или ответа;
- стремиться к максимальному количеству правок и минимальному количеству комментариев.

Все это вместе значительно облегчит восприятие темы теми людьми, которые позднее придут на Stack Overflow и будут искать ответ на схожий вопрос. В результате, и задавая вопрос, и отвечая на него, участники будут создавать темы интересные и полезные не только в момент решения конкретной проблемы и не только участникам обсуждения, но и гораздо позднее всем тем, кто будет искать решение подобной задачи.

#### В каких случаях следует использовать комментарии?

Используйте комментарии:

- если вы хотите попросить автора ответа или вопроса об уточнении;
- если, помимо голоса “за” и/или принятия ответа, вы хотите выразить благодарность;
- если вы хотите дополнить чужой ответ своим экспертным мнением.

#### В каких случаях следует публиковать ответ?

Пользуйтесь формой публикации ответа:

- если вы хотите предоставить какую-либо информацию, которая может помочь решить обозначенную в вопросе задачу;
- во всех остальных отличных от комментариев случаях.

#### Когда следует публиковать ответ вместо комментария?

С большой вероятностью будет верно опубликовать ответ вместо комментария:

- если вы адресуете комментарий автору вопроса через @;
- если размер вашего комментария превышает допустимое количество символов;
- если ваш комментарий содержит большое количество разметки MarkDown;
- если, форматируя ваш комментарий, вы используете поле ввода для ответа.

Все это необходимо для достижения одной цели - выделить вопрос и ответы и сосредоточить все внимание читающего тему на них.

***Вопрос создается один раз, но его решение используется многократно!***

Comment: "*если ... вы используете поле ввода для ответа*" - странноватая рекомендация. во-первых, в комменте особо не разойдёшься :) во-вторых, я это делаю *всегда*, если предполагается хоть что-то, отличное от обратных кавычек/звёздочек. даже ссылки. просто затем, чтобы не корёжить коммент банальной опечаткой и не дёргаться потом на редактирование.

Answer (score 7):

> уточнять исходный ответ вместо создания дополнительных так, чтобы в каждой теме был только один ответ от одного автора

В общем случае неверно. Хотя обычно ответ от одного автора должен быть один, и множественные ответы часто являются признаком того, что пользователь заблудился в интерфейсе (хотя вообще-то там кнопка со специальной надписью и отдельным предупреждением...), но вообще-то существуют случаи, когда ответов на один вопрос может быть несколько.

Возьмём, например, вопрос "Как сделать X в языке Y?" Если ответы сами по себе достаточно сложные, значительно отличаются, и автор ответов не может однозначно сказать, какой ответ лучше, то может быть разумным разделить их. Тогда сообщество сможет решить голосованием, какой ответ лучше; тогда обсуждение в комментариях различных подходов к решению задачи будет отдельно.

Впрочем, здесь однозначного мнения нет. См. [What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice)

Особняком стоит Мета, где множественные ответы на один вопрос — это норма. Здесь голосование используется не для оценки качества ответа, а для выражения мнения за или против. Поэтому, если вы хотите выразить несколько различных точек зрения или предложить несколько вариантов для голосования, то важно разделить ответ на несколько отдельных ответов.

> В каких случаях следует использовать комментарии?
>
> - если, помимо голоса “за” и/или принятия ответа, вы хотите выразить благодарность

Давайте не будем учить подобному флуду хотя бы в официальных FAQ?

> Когда следует публиковать ответ вместо комментария?
>
> - если вы адресуете комментарий автору вопроса через @

Обращение в ответах не работает.

> - если лимит количества комментариев исчерпан, но вы еще не выразили вашу идею

На Stack Overflow нет лимита на комментарии. После определённого порога появляется ссылка для переноса обсуждения в чат, но она ни к чему не обязывает.

Comment: под лимитом на количество комментариев скорее всего подразумевался лимит на количество символов в комментарии

Comment: @PashaPash, нет, на ХК был лимит на количество комментариев во избежание длительных дискуссий. Но пользователи всегда недоумевали и разводили [meta-tag:нытье] по этому поводу.

Comment: @Nofate русские лимиты - бессмысленные и беспощадные

Comment: @PashaPash, чатов не было, а языком почесать всем хотелось )

Comment: По поводу 

> Обращение в ответах не работает.

Имелось в виду, если пользователь обращается к автору вопроса в комментариях, то скорее всего стоит публиковать ответ, а не комментарий. Естественно, ответ не будте содержать обращения через `@`, так как он по умолчанию адресован автору вопроса.

Comment: А если лимит комментариев не исчерпан, но я все-равно не могу обратится к человеку. В других вопросах могу, а в одном не могу. Когда пишу @ и имя, то оно не подсвечивается. В чем может быть причина ?

Comment: @alex Обращение к автору поста избыточно и удаляется. Обращение может быть только одно.

Answer (score -3):

А может комментарии стоит вообще убрать и оставить одни ответы? Так будет меньше путаницы.

Comment: Комментарии нужны для уточнения вопросов

Comment: Тогда некоторые люди не получат помощи. Частенько на вопрос неохота подробно отвечать, а комментария достаточно, чтобы направить спрашивающего в нужное русло

Comment: имхо все то же самое можно сделать в ответах. Тогда хотя бы не будет в глазах рябить от мелкого шрифта. И второй минус, что обсуждение разрывается на части и трудно найти какую-то последовательность.