# Почему не приветствуются длинные дискуссии?

Tags: обсуждение, правила

Почему на StackOverflow на русском языке не приветствуются длинные дискуссии?

Comment: SO - не место для дискуссий.

Answer (score 7):

Потому что:

- StackOverflow - это база знаний в формате Q&A, а не уютный дискуссионный форум.
- Для дискуссий у нас есть [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

См. темы:

- [Комментарий или ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419)
- [Как и какие вопросы следует закрывать? В каких случаях?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271)
- [Зачем нужен Stack Overflow на русском?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/173)

Comment: Чат — это хорошо. А можно кнопочку «Чат» поднять вверх на видное место, а то не все имеют терпение доходить до низа и найти его.

Comment: Сверху тоже есть: http://i.imgur.com/Yb7fL8Z.png

Comment: О да! Более лучшей нычки не нашли? Интересно часто ли туда заходят?

Comment: @Arik, Вы опоздали года  на два-три. Теперь это в самом деле не место для дискуссий (== развития программера) а источник пополнения некой базы знаний в формате Q&A gameplay. Предполагаю, что скоро ее скормят какой-нибудь нейронной сети от Google и ... (интересно, насколько повысится глюкавость программ. которые будут ваяться в соответствии с ее однозначными советами?).

Comment: @avp, а вы видели http://gkoberger.github.io/stacksort/ ? )

Comment: @Nofate, раньше не видел. Сейчас попробовал и что-то у меня ничего не заработало (чья глюкавость?)

Comment: @avp Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [этот вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/643/).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, OK, думаю мы поняли друг друга. Постараюсь более не помогать искать ошибки людям на этом сайте.