# Какие комментарии неуместны на Stack Overflow на Русском?

Tags: поддержка, faq, комментарии

Некоторые участники используют комментарии вида:

> как насчет погуглить? Пробовали? Говорят, что помогает. Экономит время.

> А вообще, неплохо было бы, если бы вы сначала погуглили

> как насчет использовать тот же метод (`String.split()`) в `Java`? Или хотя бы набраться смелости и попробовать **погуглить, прежде чем задавать такой вопрос**?

> а вариант с погуглить по ссылке, которую я дал?

> Вот вам даже ссылка в гугл

> открываете гугл и спрашиваете у него `android webview get html`. Переходите по первой ссылке и копируете код оттуда. Вы вообще пробовали сами искать?

Примеры других время от времени допускаемых ошибок:

> ViewPager же, нет?

> Это обычная проблема. В элементе списка есть кликабельный View - кнопка.

> стыдно быть настолько ленивым.

> `SUBSTRING` - mysql.ru/docs/maryan/#substring

И так далее…

### Какие комментарии неуместны на Stack Overflow на Русском:

1. **Комментарии, содержащие развернутые ответы**. Stack Overflow – это сайт вопросов и ответов. Комментарии нужны исключительно в тех случаях, когда автор вопроса или ответа хочет запросить дополнительную информацию, и в идеале должны удаляться после ее получения. Публикация дополнений к вопросу или ответу, ответов или новых вопросов в комментариях напрямую противоречит идеологии проекта.
2. **Комментарии-ответы, состоящие только из ссылок**. Как говорится выше, ответам не место в комментариях. Любой ответ на вопрос должен публиковаться в виде ответа. Если вы можете помочь коллеге решением, но у вас нет времени на развернутый ответ, пожалуйста, воздержитесь от публикации комментария-ответа, состоящего из ссылки: либо опубликуйте минимально необходимый ответ со ссылкой на источник (тем более вы сможете дополнить ответ в будущем), либо воздержитесь от публикации ответа вовсе, его напишет тот, у кого есть время. Наша цель – создать базу прикладных решений, а не создать пополняемую вручную поисковую выдачу, с этой задачей поисковики справятся без нас.
3. **Отсылка в поисковик**. На мой взгляд, в наше время про поисковик знают практически все слои населения, конечно же, разработчики не исключение. Уже множество раз обсуждалось, что *[для публикации вопроса на сайте требуется потратить намного больше сил и времени по сравнению с поиском ответа в поисковике](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2166/6)*. Уверен, сегодня комментарий с предложением воспользоваться поисковиком будет неактуален и неуместен даже на сайте, например, парикмахеров.
4. **Шутки, насмешки и издевательства**. Здесь очень важно ответить себе на вопрос – «Какова ваша цель участия в сообществе?». Поделиться знаниями с сообществом? Поддержать коллегу в сложной ситуации? Создать базу знаний, чтобы решение задач занимало меньше времени? Повысить интерес к программированию среди населения? Найти решение проблемы? Если ваш ответ(ы) выглядит примерно так же, поздравляю! Нам с вами по пути. Но если вы хотите унижать менее квалифицированных коллег или практиковаться в каламбуре, простите, но в Интернете существуют более подходящие для этого сайты. Публикуя шуточные или унижающие достоинство комментарии, с большой вероятностью вы никогда не побудите автора прочитать больше книг, автор не станет публиковать более расширенное описание проблемы, автор не повысит свою профессиональную квалификацию. Он(а) найдет ресурс, где исключительно в профессиональной дружелюбной манере укажут на проблему и приведут возможные способы решения.

Подобные комментарии не приносят пользу ни автору вопроса, ни сообществу в целом. Участники Stack Overflow, особенно с большой репутаций, являются, от части, примером для индустрии. Строя отношения в сообществе на добродетели, отзывчивости и исключительно профессиональных знаниях, мы показываем отличный пример не только коллегам, но и всему Рунету.

### Что делать, если вопрос или ответ не соответствуют качеству сайта?

- Проголосовать против.
- Оставить сигнал тревоги.
- [Добавить уточняющий комментарий о том, как улучшить сообщение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1225/6).
- Внести улучшающую правку.

### Что дальше?

Победить указанные проблемы можно только всем сообществом. Пожалуйста, отмечайте сигналом тревоги подобные комментарии как требующие внимания модератора.

Хочется отметить, что отсылки в поисковик и насмешки над коллегами полностью противоречат идеологии Stack Overflow. Мы будем настойчиво просить авторов подобных комментариев воздержаться от публикации содержимого данного характера на сайте.

**Создать квалифицированное русскоязычное сообщество программистов можно только вместе!**

---

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на сообщения на Мете:

- [«Пожалуйста, не отправляйте новичков в поисковики»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/).
- [«Ответ-ссылка не приветствуется?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1805/).
- [Простые вопросы, лентяи и т. д.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/681/6).
- [«Ответ или комментарий»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419/).
- [«Что делать, если вопрос вызывает злость?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-friendly).
- [«Будьте дружелюбными»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: а как насчёт [такого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484123/#comment560675_484123) комментария?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Ну да, не самый лучший комментарий, каюсь. У вас есть лучше идея, как донести до автора абсолютную невежливость и грубость вопросов в императиве? Подскажите.

Comment: @VladD: а мне нравится, он с юмором, в рамках приличия и соответствует вопросу.

Comment: И что, совет почитать `man ...` (со ссылкой на него) надо оформлять ответом? А если подобный комментарий логичен только в контексте уже ранее данных комментариев? Т.о. с безоговорочностью пункта 2 я не согласен, правильное решение слишком зависит от ситуации.

Comment: Считаю, что п.2 лучше, чем ничего. Комментарий не мешает появлению полноценных ответов (если кто-то сможет их дать), автор вопроса более других участников способен оценить пригодность информации по ссылке и дать самоответ, прямое копирование в ответ может быть ограничено лицензией контента, на который ведет ссылка.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky♦  Очередной Мао дзе Дун, который строем хочет всех загнать в светлое будущее. Люди, не обращайте внимание на очередного дуче. Он может представлять интерес лишь для психиатров. Пишите те комментарии, которые сами сочтете нужными.

Comment: @avp Надо любой комментарий обязательно визировать у Nicolas Chabanovsky♦ю Иначе вы будете забанены.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, мне непонятны ваши претензии к Nicolas. Вопрос вынесен на обсуждение, каждый волен обоснованно выразить свое мнение (что, например, и сделал Dmitriy Simushev).

Comment: В пункте про поисковики забыли упомянуть самую главную проблему таких комментариев - эффект поисковой рекурсии

Answer (score 35):

Я откровенно **против** пункта 2.

На мой взгляд, он вызван только желанием какой-то "стерильности" ru.SO и не помогает авторам вопросов получить ответ. Совсем не помогает. Я понимаю, что ru.SO это прежде всего база знаний, но не нужно вдаваться в крайности и совсем пренебрегать интересами авторов вопросов.

Если у кого-то нет времени отвечать развернуто на вопрос, то комментарий с конкретной ссылкой (не на поисковик) намного *лучше чем ничего*. Автор вопроса, может *сразу* пройти по ссылке и найти какую-то полезную для себя информацию. Если его вопрос будет решен - прекрасно. А если нет, то он всегда может подождать развернутого ответа на свой вопрос.

В тоже время, другой участник сообщества, у которого есть время и желание опубликовать ответ может пройти по ссылке-комментарию, сформулировать правильный ответ и опубликовать его от своего имени. Ответивший получит репутацию, сообщество получит ответ на вопрос, а автор вопроса получит развернутый ответ (если он еще не нашел его по ссылке).

Comment: Подпишусь под каждым абзацем. Нам всетаки надо ехать, а не шашечки.

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы после публикации ответа–ссылки в комментарии другие участники публиковали развернутые ответы. К сожалению, это бывает далеко не всегда. Самое страшное, что отвечая ссылкой, участники продолжают размещать ответы в комментариях (в двух или трех, так как в один ответ не помещается). Вторая проблема – общая тенденция. Видя как поступают опытные участники, все начинают делать так же. Так сайт может превратиться в список ссылок, а не базу знаний. Надо искать какой-то компромис.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, значит нужно пропагандировать преобразование комментариев-ссылок в ответы, силами активных участников сообщества. Авторам вопросов в большинстве случаев нет никакого дела до "базы знаний". У них есть вопрос, им нужен ответ. Если ТС чуть опытнее школьника, то хорошей ссылки в правильном направлении обычно хватает, чтобы помочь ему самому найти решение. Понятно, что качественный ответ во много раз лучше, но ссылка точно лучше чем ничего. Я считаю, что запрет комментариев-ссылок может привести к новой фазе "Проблемы Новичков".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, еще одной причиной комментариев-ссылок может служить низкая ценность репутации на ru.SO: отвечающим проще кинуть ссылку в комментарий, тем самым выполнив свой моральный долг перед сообществом, и не утруждать себя написанием качественного ответа. Я считаю, что как только уровень репутации на ru.SO будет иметь какое-то значение где-то кроме самого сообщества, сразу найдутся люди, готовые преобразовывать комментарии-ссылки в ответы

Comment: Еще автор может сам написать ответ, когда найдет решение по ссылке.