# Бан за "Вы пробовали искать решение самостоятельно?"

Tags: обсуждение

Уже который раз подвергаюсь террору со стороны модераторов за попытку борьбы с наглостью и ленью авторов вопросов, содержимое которых сводится к "*у меня такая-то проблема, сделайте все за меня*". Сообщение модератора содержит следующее:

> Отправка в поисковик и указания на личностные недостатки автора
>   вопроса никак не способствуют нашей общей миссии, более того, они
>   разобщают нас!

---

> PS Хочу также обратить ваше внимание, что согласно правилам сообщества
>   в случае последующих «погуглить сначала не пробовал?» блокировка
>   доступа к учетной записи будет на год.

Меня интересует вопрос, **что это за беспредел?**

Формально я задаю вопрос, который мне должен помочь дать ответ на вопрос. Да, и одному только мне известно, как он мне поможет, и действительно ли этот вопрос может мне помочь. Если бы мне помог ответ на вопрос "Как зовут вашу собаку?", то его бы я тоже оставил, и никто не был бы в праве подвергать сомнению тот факт, что я считаю, что он поможет мне дать ответ на вопрос. Это достоверно известно только мне.

Прошу объяснить связь моих уточняющих вопросов, и угрозы бана.

---

Касательно

> «погуглить сначала не пробовал?»

Я не использовал данную формулировку в комментариях. Это цитата из сообщения модератора @Nicolas Chabanovsky♦, которую он, видимо, придумал сам. Я никогда не обращался к участникам сообщества на "Ты"

Comment: Чем ответ на вопрос "погуглить сначала не пробовал?" может помочь вам дать ответ на вопрос? Поделитесь пожалуйста, раз уже это вам известно. В противном случае **любой** вправе подвергать сомнению тот факт, что ответ "да, пробовал" или "нет, лень" вам хоть как-то поможет.

Comment: @PashaPash, например, стоит ли мне самому искать ответ на данный вопрос в гугле. Я часто так делаю - прочитал вопрос, но решения не знаю - иду в гугл, нахожу решение, оформляю ответ.

Comment: Тогда вам стоит именно так формулировать комментарий. что-то вроде "пробовал погуглить? Если нет, скажи - я погуглю за тебя и попробую что-нибудь найти". Формулировка "погуглить сначала не пробовал?" и "тебя что, в гугле забанили?" воспринимается многими (да почти всеми) как агрессивный риторический вопрос. Точно так же, как "ты что, идиот?" воспринимается как оскорбление, а не как мирный вопрос о наличии у топикастера  глубокой степени олигофрении. Хоть знание о возможных проблемах со здоровьем топикастера, вкупе с именем его собаки и может помочь вам дать ответ.

Comment: Приведите больше примеров.

Comment: @PashaPash, вы считаете, что мне стоит изменить формулировку комментариев на что-то вроде "Вы пытались искать решение самостоятельно?", или "Ответ на ваш вопрос можно найти при помощи поисковика, потратив примерно 18 секунд"?

Comment: @metalurgus первый вариант - да, вполне нейтральный. второй - нет, я бы не советовал его использовать.

Comment: @PashaPash, а что делать, в случае, когда поиск ответа на вопрос действительно занимает меньше минуты? Каким образом научить\заставить автора вопроса пользоваться поиском преджде, чем задавать вопрос? Я думал, что если показать, насколько это быстро и просто, это может принести результаты...

Comment: @metalurgus радоваться, что вы так хорошо умеете гуглить. "Просто и быстро" отсекается, например, незнанием языка (для вас это не проблема, для многих новичков - еще какая). Или неумением сформулировать вопрос гуглу (то же самое, да еще гугл повадился исправлять запросы за пользователя). Или просто незнанием термина - нужно заранее знать что именно надо гуглить. Всегда лучше оформить полноценный ответ - что при попытке задать вопрос сайт включает встроенный поиск по заголовку. Так что сам факт наличия вопроса с нормальным ответом снизит поток новых негуглителей.

Comment: Можно запросить проверяемую информацию о том, совершал ли ТС запрос: "какие поисковые запросы вы уже делали в поисках решения?". Не могу судить, насколько корректно это в контексте ru.SO, но это всяко получше чем "погуглить не пробовал?".

Comment: представьте Гитлер  (нехороший человек) задаст полезный вопрос по тематике ru.SO Если вы думаете что, на такой вопрос не следует отвечать, то вы ошибаетесь: моральный облик автора вопроса не имеет значения, если сам вопрос хороший. Конкретный пример: ["как выполнить внешнюю команду в Питоне"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/4279)—отсылать в поисковик неуместно (отношение с точностью наоборот: stack overflow—это место куда поисковик посылает (место назначения)). Я ничего не знаю об авторе (наглый ли, лентяй ли он, тупой ли он итд). Я знаю только то что вопрос полезный. (точка)

Comment: @metalurgus Проблема не в конкретном обращении на вы или на [ты](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/260404/6), и не к конкретной формулировке, проблема [в оскорблении базовых человеческих достоинств](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/396142/6), которые вы допускаете в подобных комментариями. Если у кого–либо меньше знаний чем у вас, это не повод для их унижения.

Answer (score 17):

#### «Вы пробовали искать решение самостоятельно?» не эквивалентно «погуглить сначала не пробовал?»

Слова имеют значение. Более того, порой два одинаковых предложения, сказанные с разной интонацией и выражением лица, воспринимаются абсолютно по-разному. Так сложилось, что практически любая отсылка к поисковику воспринимается как агрессия (подробнее: «[Какие комментарии неуместны на Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2349/)»).

#### Уже который раз подвергаюсь террору со стороны модерраторов за попытку борьбы с наглостью и ленью авторов вопросов

[Вопрос о том, что задать вопрос намного сложнее, чем найти ответ через поисковик рассматривался не один раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2166/6). На мой взгляд, проблема в том, что наши начинающие коллеги зачастую просто не знают опорных слов для поиска информации. Быстрый поиск – это навык, приобретаемый с опытом.  Более того, возможно, они нашли информацию по теме, но не смогли в полной мере разобраться, в связи своей квалификации *начального уровня*.

#### Прошу объяснить связь моих уточняющих вопросов, и угрозы бана.

Сожалею, если формулировка прозвучала как угроза. Этой фразой лишь хотел напомнить о правиле роста блокировки по экспоненте, которому мы в настоящий момент стараемся придерживаться. Поскольку предыдущая блокировка была на месяц, следующая будет на год. Уверен, все очень ценят ваш вклад в развитие проекта и желание помогать коллегам, но правила едины для всех без исключений.

<sub>К слову, в прошлом, у вас уже было четыре блокировки на Stack Overflow за подобные нарушение, и, если мне не изменяет память, как минимум две аналогичные на ХэшКоде.</sub>

#### А что делать, в случае, когда поиск ответа на вопрос действительно занимает меньше минуты?

Хочу подчеркнуть идею, что все, что вы находите через поисковик было когда–то кем–то задано. [Даже самые простые и, казалось бы очевидные вещи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1811/). Пожалуйста, вспомните, что до появления Stack Overflow, решение большинства простых задач занимало дни, а иногда и недели! Stack Overflow – позволяет структурировать информацию в наиболее оптимальном виде «вопрос–ответ», благодаря чему, вам не надо читать по 20 страниц обсуждения политики и личных качеств автора темы на форуме по программированию, чтобы найти нужные ключи для компилятора. Теперь это решается за несколько секунд!

Это возможно, благодаря тому, что люди задают вопросы! Самые разные. И сложные, *и простые*!

Помогать коллегам невероятно приятно и крайне полезно для личности человека. Возможно, вы уже не помните то возбуждение, когда потратив несколько дней, находишь решение, и замечаешь, что ты можешь помочь коллеге, по сути, подарив это жизненное время ему, просто показав, как именно ты решил задачу!

Можете найти решение менее чем за минуту? Слишком просто? – [Пожалуйста, пройдите мимо!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-friendly) Уверен, найдутся те, для кого это не просто, кто вложился своим личным временем, чтобы разобраться, те, кому *публикация ответа на этот вопрос принесет радость*! Радость, от возможности поделиться своим успехом и от осознания помощи другим.

#### Каким образом научить\заставить автора вопроса пользоваться поиском прежде, чем задавать вопрос?

Списывая данный факт на особенности менталитета, все же, хочу подчеркнуть: *на Stack Overflow участники обучают друг друга программированию*. Учить «как правильно жить» – задача совершенно других институтов, выходящая за рамки сообщества.

#### Я думал, что если показать, насколько это быстро и просто, это может принести результат.

Лучший способ показать «насколько это просто» – опубликовать развернутый ответ. Мы видели не раз, когда после публикации ответа, автор вопроса упрекал себя за «глупость». (На самом деле, глупости никакой нет. Проблема всегда очевидна и тривиальна, если знаешь решение.)

**Дополнительно**

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на вопрос «[Работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)»

Comment: >>«Вы пробовали искать решение самостоятельно?» не эквивалентно «погуглить сначала не пробовал?» 
Я знаю, я так и не писал. Это вы мне привели такой пример, взяв его с потолка.

Comment: Вы сейчас меня "ругаете" за фразу, которую вы сами придумали. Очень остроумно и логично.

Comment: Это отлично отражает последовательность и логичность вашей работы, как модератора.

Comment: @metalurgus За все время вы использовали множество вариаций этой фразы. Например, вчера была и такая «[как насчет погуглить сначала? Пробовали?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579318/)». Как мне кажется, искать среди подобных комментариев ссылку на приведенный пример, не является правильной стратегией, так как проблема системная. Что «Вы пробовали искать решение самостоятельно?», что  «погуглить сначала не пробовал?», хоть не эквивалентны в терминах вежливости, но приводят к одному и тому же эффекту – отторжению от русскоязычного сообщества разработчиков.

Comment: @metalurgus Вы, как один из участников с большой репутацией, являетесь «примером» поведения в сообществе. Подобные комментарии (как и отношение к коллегам в общем) не только прививают нежелание общаться в сообществе новичкам, но и показывает другим знатокам, «как надо поступать с коллегами».

Comment: А вы, являсь еще более значимым примером, как модератор сообщества, позволяете себе клеветать. Как только выпишете бан себе, можете смело банить и меня. Потому, как, очевидно, что *клевета* является куда более серьезным проявлением агрессии и злости, чем мои комментарии.

Comment: @metalurgus, у вас минимум 92 отправления участников в гугл. Одни повежливее, другие - погрубее.

Comment: @Nofate, я уже отправил заявку на удаление профиля, идите лесом

Comment: Отличный ответ. И сходу маленький вопросец -- отправка в гугл *с набором слов для успешного поиска* тоже теперь расценивается как оскорбительное действие?

Comment: @avp думаю, это вполне адекватная помощь, если автор не знает даже что гуглить, что бывает нередко.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я тоже так всегда считал (особенно когда отвечать некогда (или лень)). Но похоже теперь это расходится с политикой сайта (я так понимаю, что с некоторых пор главное не помощь конкретному программеру, а накопление базы знаний)

Comment: @avp это все еще допустимо - но только если вопрос будет удален

Comment: @avp в противном случае по вашим же ключевым словам гугл этот вопрос и найдет :)

Comment: @avp на мой взгляд акцент на том, что в гугл можно послать аккуратно, а можно грубо.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, тогда появится цель -- сменить гугл

Comment: @avp сменить к-сожалению-все-еще-лучший поисковик ... на что? xD Не будет такой цели.

Comment: @Nofate, понятно, что грубить нехорошо, но и цацкаться со всеми обидчивыми тоже не стоит

Comment: @PavelMayorov, на более адекватный велосипед (Вы же привели пример его тупости (ну, пока она еще не столь велика))

Comment: @avp тупость? вы о чем? Подобное поведение будет врожденным для любой поисковой системы.

Comment: @avp Все зависит от целей, которые мы, сообщество, ставим перед собой. Если бы задача была помочь одному только автору вопроса, возможно, комментарий, в виде поисковой фразы, имел бы значение. Миссия SO – создать многократно используемую базу готовых решений, попадая на которую из поисковика, пользователь смогу бы получить _ответ на свой вопрос__ за считанные секунды. (Подчеркну, ответ на вопрос, а не новую поисковую фразу для поиска). На SO ответы публикуются для всех, кто придет из поиска, а не автора вопроса. Отсюда и требования. Пользу подхода мы можем оценить сами попав на SO из поиска.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, забыли слово *примитивной* (в любой поисковой системы), впрочем это тема, которая не может обсуждаться, т.к. *вызывает бесконечные споры и ...* (как там это формулируется?)

Comment: @avp Представьте, что бы было если бы вместо ответов на SO были бы только ключевые слова для поиска. Не думаю, что это сильно бы помогло человечеству.

Comment: @avp добавлю ссылку: https://habrahabr.ru/post/311322/#comment_9837214

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, если серьезно, то я двумя руками за **хорошие ответы**. (особенно если они выстраданы автором а не переписаны из книг (и др. подобных источников)). Но, я также против административных ограничений. Такая, вот, неоднозначная позиция по многим вопросам на сайте.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, [Закат SO](https://habrahabr.ru/post/311322/#comment_9837214) интересно-то как, почитаю

Comment: @avp Свобода – это хорошо, анархия – это плохо. Правила должны давать свободу и направлять нас в направлении оптимального развития, ограничивая возможность нанесения вреда себе. Я не знаю ни одной системы не содержащей  ограничений.

Comment: @avp Если вам интересна тема развития сообщества (или его заката), пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [публикацию в блоге](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/10/Podcast-89-The-Decline-of-Stack-Overflow-Has-Been-Greatly-Exaggerated/).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, попробовал почитать эту дискуссию, но как-то все там очень занудно (возможно из-за моего "знания"  английского...)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky отличный ответ. Правда.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, для того, что бы свобода не переходила в анархию, она должна быть обоснована. Если бы за каждый минус минусующий должен был бы отчитаться обязательным комментарием "почему?", это намного улучшило бы сообщество. Автор знал бы за что минус, остальные участники тоже, а заодно позволило бы выявить, кто использует минусы как подрывную деятельность. Что-то мне подсказывает, эта инициатива не пройдет, но задумайтесь об этом.

Comment: @AlexKrass, однозначно не пройдет, поскольку может вызвать "войну минусований", а если копнуть глубже, то отсутствие анонимности в конечном итоге противоречит принятой в данном обществе политкорректности, которая в свою очередь ... (впрочем, это тема уже не для программистского сайта)

Comment: @AlexKrass Сейчас, до достижения определенной репутации, если участник голосует против, ему показывается выплывающая подсказка, что следует оставить комментарий.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky которую успешно все игнорируют)) Ну да ладно, это проблема не сайта, это проблема менталитета некоторых людей.

Answer (score 15):

Отправлять в гугл нежелательно по довольно простой причине - ru.SO имеет в гугле хороший рейтинг, и на любой вопрос могут прийти из гугла совершенно посторонние люди.

Согласитесь, прийти на вопрос из гугла и увидеть посыл в гугл - довольно неприятно?

Отправлять в гугл - можно, но только если у вопроса крупные проблемы с качеством. При этом требуется заминусовать и закрыть вопрос, чтобы он удалился через некоторое время. Надо следить за тем, совпадает ли мнение других участников с вашим относительно судьбы вопроса, поскольку в открытых или плюсовых вопросах посылы в гугл нежелательны.

---

В любом случае, посылать в гугл надо корректно. *"погуглить сначала не пробовал?"* - это довольно грубый наезд.

Как минимум, к незнакомому собеседнику надо обращаться безлично или на "вы". Также желательно объяснить причину, по которой ответ следовало искать в гугле, а не тут.

Answer (score 4):

*Изначально писалось в виде комментария, но выросло до существенного объёма.*

---

Считаю нужным упомянуть, что @NicolasChabanovsky действительно [был замечен за принятием мер по крайне сомнительному поводу](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29993936#29993936) сходной природы. Он постоянно совершенствует свои критерии классификации комментариев, но он человек и иногда ошибается.

И столкнувшись с несправедливым решением, обратиться к сообществу очень даже логично.

### ...но что если вы действительно неправы?

Случайных прохожих, коими является немалая часть задающих здесь вопросы, на самом деле мало волнует, как вы к кому бы там ни было относитесь.

Поэтому когда вы оставляете комментарий, в котором больше негатива (яркого высказывания прямого неуважения), чем конструктива (нейтральных указаний на то, что стоит сделать), в большей степени воспринимается именно негатив, который мало кому нравится и чаще игнорируется или отбивается негативом в ответ.

Это, разумеется, не карт-бланш на «Поищите ответ на ваш вопрос в поисковике», идеально подходящий под формулу выше, остальные местные нормы хорошего тона по-прежнему в силе. Но это же можно сформулировать и менее явными способами. Например:

> По каким поисковым запросам вы пробовали найти ответ на ваш вопрос?

Этот вопрос [*предполагает добрые намерения*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Что автор *не глупый* и **уже** сходил в поисковик, прежде чем обращаться сюда. Это прямо видно из вопроса. И даже если он этого реально не сделал, с хорошей вероятностью сделает, прежде чем отвечать на этот вопрос. И если очень повезёт, он запомнит, что это могут спросить и лучше делать заранее. И прямой ответ на этот вопрос это проверяемая информация.

Comment: А если совсем повезет, то он научится сам искать информацию и мы станем не нужны.

Comment: @avp как это не нужны? Он же будет её находить на том же SO :)

Comment: @alexolut поначалу. Потом, если повезёт, перейдёт на уровень поиска в исходниках или дизасме. Хотя это я, наверное, размечтался.

Comment: @D-side апокалиптичные мечты, однако :)

Answer (score 1):

Меня тоже порой раздражают вопросы, ответы на которые гуглятся ~мгновенно. Но я помню как сам искал в поисковике ответы на тривиальные вопросы часами и ничего не мог найти из-за неумения правильно сформулировать вопрос и понять ответ. Засим я действую в таких случаях [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/556124/17609)

1. Вбиваем в гугл:

   > [правильный поисковый запрос](https://www.google.ru/)
2. Идём по первой [ссылке на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/)
3. Копируем код:

   ```
    тут код, скопипащенный с en-SO
   ```

Таким образом я и ответ даю и показываю как и где можно было это найти в надежде хотя бы так показать как можно было воспользоваться поиском в этом конкретном случае.

Comment: 4. Ставлю ссылку на оригинал.

Comment: @Other, это уже во втором пункте) Можете убедиться, пройдя по первой ссылке в ответе

Comment: Пунктом нагляднее :) Но идея хорошая, не против, если я подобно делать буду?

Comment: @Other, да я только за)

Comment: Желательно все же давать хоть немного перевода объяснений.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, когда есть что переводить, то перевод есть. В некоторых случаях для ответа достаточно имени метода

Comment: Вы забыли главный пункт: "я применяю свои знания предмета и опыт работы, чтобы найти практичный ответ среди моря океана откровенного мусора", который может быть совсем неочевиден новичку (то что вы нашли ответ на enSO ещё не говорит о полезности этого ответа для вопроса автора (или даже исходного вопроса: я видел ошибочные ответы с 100+ голосов «за»). На Stack Overflow  жемчужины легче найти чем на сайтах в других форматах, но это не значит что всё или даже большинство является истиной в последней инстанции).

Answer (score 1):

А каким образом отвечать на такие вопросы?
[Консольный анализатор выражений и их вычисление Swift](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582135/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-swift). Тут я чётко вижу студента, который хочет, чтобы за него решили лабу. И помочь с этим я бы рад, но вся помощь тут будет "разбивай строку на токены таким то методом, ну и считай, если нужны приоритеты - есть такой-то способ сортировки выражения по приоритету". И этого будет более чем достаточно для человека ищущего. Для человека ленящегося это не скажет ничего. Он скажет - давай код. Получается я должен буду написать алгоритм разбиения, анализа, приоритизации и вычисления. Зачем мне это писать, если это не будет помощью другим ищущим людям, а простым частным решением частной задачи? И я так понимаю это сообщество не ставит целью решение частных задач, а поиск ответов на вопросы, которые затрагивают случайного программиста в этой области. А программист бы искал решение вида "У меня есть строка, мне нужно вычленить операции и числа", "как определить приоритет основываясь на плоской записи вида число-оператор-число-оператор". Отвечающий не должен придумывать способ хранения данных, форму их передачи между алгоритмами, при этом ещё и писать сами алгоритмы, такие задачи надо скидывать фрилансеров, а не на комьюнити.

Таки теперь вопрос - как вести себя в таки вопросах, когда действительно согласен помочь - попытаться узнать какой есть фундамент, что он уже нагуглил, что нет, понимает ли он вообще, как работать со строкой языке, о котором он спрашивает, и знает ли он вообще какой-нибудь язык. Если ответы на всё нет-нет-нет, то таких спрашивателей нужно посылать в гугл или в электронную библиотеку, это будет не грубо, не резко, в этом будет проявлено намного больше уважения, чем в их вопросе, который, как мне кажется, сам оскорбляет всё комьюнити.

Comment: Вопрос хороший, только вы его опубликовали ответом, а ответы на ответы не предусмотрены движком сайта. Рекомендую опубликовать как вопрос ) http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask. А на этот вопрос можно ссылку оставить для объяснения контекста.

Answer (score 0):

Я вот что хочу сказать по сути того, что привело к этой теме.

Новичков всегда больше, чем опытных специалистов. Новички всегда задают простые вопросы, на которые в большинстве случаев можно найти ответы простым поиском.

Но кроме нубов и профи есть ещё участники с промежуточными градациями опыта и знаний. Вот им-то и нужно оставлять эти вопросы.

Это происходит так: научившись чему-нибудь, человеку (не всегда, но часто) хочется похвастать своими знаниями, поделиться опытом, ну и репутации заработать. И он вполне может начать отвечать на те самые нубские вопросы, которые сам задавал несколько месяцев назад.

Вам кажутся эти вопросы глупыми и наивными? Пусть так. Просто оставьте их тем, кто с радостью возьмется за ответы на них. Сделав домашнюю работу за других десяток раз, они сами перейдут на следующую ступень и перестанут (должны перестать!) реагировать на мольбы "сделайте мне!". А на их место придут другие, вчерашние новички.

---

Тут возникает такая проблема: если помечать как дубликаты и закрывать такие вопросы, на которые уже есть ответы, то для начинающих не будет шанса проявить себя, показать свои едва появившиеся знания.

Мне кажется в этом одна из причин умирания многих форумов, бывших ранее популярными: старожилы брюзжат "Пользуйтесь поиском!", "Это уже было!", RTFM! STFW! и т. п. В итоге новички уходят на новый, недавно появившийся ресурс, где ещё нет заматеревших ветеранов, и активно помогают друг другу.

И да, я понимаю, что качество ответов вчерашних новичков может оставлять лучшего. Но, всё же, нужно сперва дать им шанс ответить и поправить в случае чего. Чем совсем не дать шанса, закрыв вопрос, заминусовав попытку ответа и т. п.

Comment: "помечать как дубликаты" лучше убрать. Там совсем другая история и мотивация, которая не мешает оставить ответ, если есть что добавить.

Comment: Правильная постановка вопроса, только в качестве ответа не совсем по теме. Может лучше вынести это на обсуждение в качестве вопроса на Мете?

Comment: Вы преувеличиваете дефицит простых вопросов, а именно способность закрытия вопросов как дубликатов прекратить их существование.  Теоретически логика "старожилы ответили на все простые вопросы" убедительна, но на практике простых вопросов навалом, даже если пытаться всё что можно закрывать как дубликат. Говорю на основе эксперимента, отвечая на заметную долю вопросов в выбранной метке, я пытался накопить канонический список вопросов, чтобы не повторятся. Обладая "золотым молотом", я могу единолично закрывать вопрос как дубликат. Похожих вопросов много, но точные дубликаты НЕ преобладают.