# Рекомендации к публикации ответов: если ответ найден в интернете - давать кейворды, по каким он был найден

Tags: предложение, ответы, google-it

Я уже долгое время сам пользуюсь схемой:
Если я нашел ответ в интернете - дать окромя ответа еще и кейворды гугла, по которым удалось найти ответ.

Моя мотивация проста: это дает не просто ответ, это дает еще и некоторые знания о том, как именно гуглятся вопросы.

Думаю, что чем чаще человек будет видеть кейворды, по которым находился ответ на любой вопрос, тем быстрее он научится сам находить ответы на свои вопросы, правильно подбирая кейворды для поиска.

А находить ответы на вопросы самим — это критически важный навык для программиста любого уровня.

Почему бы не внести это как **рекомендацию**? (не правило, а именно как рекомендацию).

Comment: По-моему связанные вопросы: [1](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/317064) и [2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3922/317064). Судя по ответам, отправлять в поисковики плохо, значит, вероятно, и рекомендовать ключевые слова для поиска тоже нехорошо. Я сам так делал в комментариях несколько раз, но после прочтения этих вопросов перестал

Comment: странная логика, как по мне)

Comment: @cppquestions не то, чтобы "нехорошо", скорее это просто бесполезно. По какому запросу материал можно найти в поиске и так очевидно: это заголовок материала. Соответственно, если дана ссылка на источник (а она должна быть дана), ничего больше писать не нужно.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight  Пример реально существующего заголовка вопроса: "Как можно сгенерировать случайною строку с 16-символо (только цифры) значное число c#"  Пример ключевых слов из моего ответа на этот вопрос: "random digit string c#" . Видимо, не всегда заголовок и ключевые слова совпадают :)

Comment: + стоит не забывать что бывают заголовки в стиле "не могу найти ответ!" и "Помогите!" и они не на столько редкость как хотелось бы )

Comment: Я имел в виду заголовок вопроса, в котором есть ответ, он то обычно нормальный. Например, если ответ есть на ENSO, то из заголовка вопроса на ENSO можно взять те же ключевые слова, по которым он находится через поиск.

Answer (score 5):

Вряд ли упоминание кейвордов что-то изменит для автора вопроса или любого другого читающего ответ. Ведь если вы нашли ответ на вопрос в интернете и опубликовали об этом ответ, данный ответ на 99% будет содержать эти самые кейворды. Тут правда надо ещё понимать, искали ли вы на русском языке или уже, например, на английском. Если на русском, то возможны, как минимум, такие варианты:

- вопрошающий просто не занимался поиском, а сразу задал вопрос. В таком случае никакие ключевые слова ему не нужны вовсе, он просто ждал ответ на вопрос.
- вопрошающий искал, но не нашёл. Либо он просто необычно сформулировал задачу, например, новичок в области вопроса, либо не знает достаточного набора синонимов, смежных для решаемой задачи терминов. В полученном ответе необходимые пробелы он должен заполнить. Если заполнить не удалось, значит ответ оказался неполным.

Если ответ найден на английском и переведён на русский, ключевые слова автору скорее всего не помогут, иначе бы он, вероятно, искал ответы/задавал вопросы на английском языке. В таком случае в силу вступают варианты, описанные для русского языка, но с заменой основного языка, конечно.

В любом случае, появление в итоге ответа на ruSO сыграет на пользу самого ruSO - расширяется база QA. Когда ответ найден на самом ruSO - можно закрыть как дубликат. Если же где-то на просторах интернета, то профит для других участников нашего сайта будет только при (пере)публикации на ruSO. К тому же можно и репы поднять за появление новых знаний в виде вопрос-ответ в составе ruSO. И здесь не так важно, перевод это был с другого языка, или перепубликация с другого ресурса. Источники в любом случае стоит указать.

Comment: ответил на твой ответ другим ответом

Answer (score 0):

В связи с комментарием под моим ответом на SO:

> Осторожнее, мне тут за косвенные призывы погуглить, бан на сутки влепили. (c) aepot

Вспомнил про этот вопрос на Мете.

---

---

---

С ответом от уважаемого **αλεχολυτ** я как не был согласен тогда, так и остался не согласным до сих пор.

Так уж вышло, что я обучал и помогал вклиниться как минимум четырём людям в айти, и как показала моя личная практика - обучение пользоваться поиском не должно быть пассивным - это не то что не эффективно, это контрэффективно.

То есть так человек учится гораздо дольше, чем если НА ПРИМЕРАХ объяснять как именно искать.

Разберем аргументы, которые привел **αλεχολυτ**

> - вопрошающий просто не занимался поиском, а сразу задал вопрос. В таком случае никакие ключевые слова ему не нужны вовсе, он просто ждал ответ на вопрос.

^ с натяжечкой могу и согласиться. Со сноской, что чтобы такое утверждать со 100% уверенностью, необходимо провести исследования, а иначе это просто "ИМХО".

НО! Есть неееекая вероятность, что в следующий раз он поищет. Если на почти каждый вопрос он будет видеть "я нашел ответ по запросу..." почти наверняка рано или поздно до него дойдет что.написать запрос и клацнуть на пару ссылок это быстрее, чем писать вопрос на SO, а потом ждать что кто-то соблаговолит ответить.

И рано или поздно мозг к этой мудрой мысли должен привыкнуть. И, внезапно, человек начнет гуглить сам! Да еще и правильным образом, т.к. у него была куча готовых примеров!

> - вопрошающий искал, но не нашёл. Либо он просто необычно сформулировал задачу, например, новичок в области вопроса, либо не знает достаточного набора синонимов, смежных для решаемой задачи терминов.

^ А вот здесь я не согласен в корне. Просто потому, что я видел как новички гуглят вопросы. Вместо набора ключевых слов они гуглят целое предложение. Как следствие, поисковик может охренеть от такого поворота событий и выдать кучу левых результатов. Вот для этой категории людей как раз таки и будет критически полезно постоянно видеть как именно гуглят "профи".

> Если ответ найден на английском и переведён на русский, ключевые слова автору скорее всего не помогут, иначе бы он, вероятно, искал ответы/задавал вопросы на английском языке.

^ Или же помогут.
Потому что не редка ситуация, когда человек хоть и знает английский на базовом уровне, но предпочитает искать информацию на русском. Потому что русский ближе. Лично мне пришлось пройти достаточно долгий путь, чтобы перейти на полностью англоязычный поиск информации, и сейчас я не задумываюсь о том, на каком языке я ищу - я просто ищу на английском. И если там не нахожу - тогда ищу на русском. Уверен, такой долгий путь проходил не я один. И этот путь можно укоротить многим людям, если человек будет видеть, что другие специалисты на ru.SO ищут информацию на английском. И, внезапно, это будет прекрасно видно, если отвечающий человек пишет ключевые слова у себя в ответе.

> В любом случае, появление в итоге ответа на ruSO сыграет на пользу самого ruSO - расширяется база QA. Когда ответ найден на самом ruSO - можно закрыть как дубликат. Если же где-то на просторах интернета, то профит для других участников нашего сайта будет только при (пере)публикации на ruSO.

^ То что я написал в самом вопросе и было сказано в рамках перепубликации + указания поисковых ключевых слов. Ресурс от этого ничего не теряет. А вот выигрывает на том, что люди будут больше учиться искать информацию сами.

> Источники в любом случае стоит указать.

^ ну лично я и указываю зачастую:

- и ответ полным текстом
- и источник (если ответом является +/- сложный код)
- и ключевые слова, по которым я нашел этот источник.

---

P.S.: А модератору, который за подобное видение может банить (хз кто там банил аэпота за подобное) стоит подумать над тем, что человек, создающий вопрос, в следующий раз может не получить свой ответ ни в принципе как ответ, ни ссылкой просто в комментарий, как это сделал аэпот. И от этого ресурс ТОЛЬКО ПРОИГРАЕТ. Поэтому советую задуматься о своем поведении и больше никого за такое не банить.

Одно дело, вычитывание и грубости, что человек не погуглил, иное дело - тактичная просьба в следующий раз гуглить + ответы-ссылки, как было сделано аепотом.

---

Примеры моих ответов:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/908244/186752

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/932232/186752

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1323275/186752

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1229894/186752

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1057515/186752

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1243613/186752

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1347818/186752

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/908244/186752

и мн. другие аналогичные ответы с указыванием ключевых слов.

Comment: aepot забанили по итогам обсуждения этого вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1345688/240512 Там не зная ответа, ничего поисковиком не найдешь, и никаких ключевых слов он не приводил. Да и забанили его не за призывы гуглить как таковые, а скорее за то, что он покусился на святое - дружелюбие к новичкам.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight значит, вероятно, необходимо улучшить систему выдачи банов таким образом, что бы человек наверняка знал за что его забанили. Ибо если бан прилетает, а человек должен догадаться за что - он не сделает правильных выводов. В даном случае aepot не знает за что его забанили. Когда меня забанили - я тоже не знал за что, пока сам не начал разбираться и выяснять что конкретно случилось.

Comment: Касательно самой идеи указывать ключевые слова - у гугла выдача очень сильно персонализирована. То, что вы смогли найти ответ «по первой же ссылке» - не означает, что остальным его выдаст хотя бы на первой странице

Comment: По поводу «в следующий раз гуглите, вместо того чтобы вопрос задать» - на мете есть вопрос где этот аргумент очень детально разобран. В следующий раз гуглите, вместо того, чтобы начинать обсуждение заново! ;))

Comment: @PashaPash прошу перечитать как вопрос так и мой ответ заново. Ибо здесь абсолютно про иное.

Comment: Ваш ответ - да, про иное. И aepot бан словил не за объяснение «как гуглить» в ответ. Хотя с баном явно был перегиб

Comment: Но в целом подход "будем учить людей гуглить на английском" - это путь "и задавать вопросы, если что - на английском и не у нас" - явно вредит ресурсу. потому что или человек реально начнет и гуглить и задавать вопросы на английском (и тогда ruSO ему не нужен), или уйдет на ресурс, где можно задать вопрос на русском и не быть посланным в английский сегмент - и то и то явно не на пользу ruSO.

Comment: Особенно если учесть, насколько ruSO плохо индексируется. в качестве примера - по "Как заблокировать клавиатуру и мышь?" - вашего ответа в результатах нет. С + C# - есть, но если бы человек погуглил на английском, перед тем, как спрашивать - то его бы не было. Был бы cyborforum и хабр. и бложики. И как результат - ваш подход приводит к ситуации "учим людей гуглить так, чтобы на ruSO вопросы не появлялись и люди к нам из поисковиков не приходили, пусть идут к конкурентам". Это какая-то странная цель для сообщества.

Comment: `Но в целом подход "будем учить людей гуглить на английском" - это путь "и задавать вопросы, если что - на английском и не у нас"` почему же? Я все так же задаю вопросы на русском по шарпу. Потому что комьюнити большое. А вот по swiftUI я задаю вопросы только на английском - потому что здесь вообще нету комьюнити ни по swiftUI ни по swift. Ну ок, по свифту капля людей есть. А на все вопросы касательно шарпа я прийду точно на ruSO. Сначала обшарив англоязычные вопросы и погуглив вопросы на русском языке. А если следовать твоей логике я должен был задавать вопрос на английском по шарпу.

Comment: Просто потому что я гуглю на английском. Из этого выходит что ИЛИ я "исключение" ИЛИ у тебя логика неправильная.