# Предвзятое отношение модератора к участнику RU SO

Tags: поддержка, модераторский-произвол

[Абстрактные классы и интерфейсы для чего и что всё же?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1360891/373567) неправомерно закрыт **модератором** Grundy как дубликат. Переоткрывать боюсь, потому что опять забанят.

Меня это задело, потому что я, еще до того как вопрос был закрыт по непонятной причине, уже дал исчерпывающий ответ автору. Пришел модератор, влепил мне минус без объяснения причин и закрыл вопрос.

Ответ по ссылке дубликата не является ответом на поставленный вопрос

> Интерфейс и абстрактный класс они же получается ссылочные типы?

Модератор **Grundy** ведет себя странно. Или просто относится ко мне предвзято, он часто минусует меня и даже банил. Прошу снять с него модераторские права, или хотя-бы отправить в отпуск, этот беспредел уже надоел.

Я уже ранее писал в саппорт по этому поводу, меня отправили на Мету, вот я и пришел. Я конечно сразу не пошел, думал пройдет. Не прошло. Этот модератор продолжает меня преследовать.

До каких пор это будет продолжаться? У меня горит со страшной силой, хочется самоудалиться.

КДПВ: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9xMx.png

Comment: да им пофик)  забей.... меня недавно забанили за то, что я интересовался возрастом автора)  типа "Комментарии помеченные тревогами и относящие не к вопросу, а личности автора:" а также "проявления невежливости". После просьбы пояснить как это относится к невежливости - ответа 0 %))  им леееень разбираться. Проще просто ткнуть и пойти дальше

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне дали бан "не отправляйте в гугл" вообще просто так, потому что кое-кто флагнул мне коммент (не адресат комментария). Скрин в посте. Я не знал, плакать или смеяться.

Comment: Тоже давно замечаю за ним подобное поведение

Comment: С гуглом это вообще нелепость какая-то

Comment: @АлексейШиманский очевидно, возраст автора относится к личности автора :) А вам он требовался для ответа на вопрос?

Comment: @demonplus и за это полагается бан? очень интересно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я не модератор, не могу ответить на этот вопрос. Просто отмечаю, что спрашивать про возраст, скорее всего, некорректно

Comment: Усомнился бы, если бы речь шла о ком-то другом.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Абстрактные классы и интерфейсы для чего и что всё же? неправомерно закрыт модератором Grundy как дубликат. Переоткрывать боюсь, потому что опять забанят.

Вопрос представляет собой беспорядочный поток сознания на тему классов и интерфейсов. Его можно закрыть как непонятный, либо дубликатом на существующий вопрос на ту же тему, и то и другое вполне правомерно. Не вижу смысла его переоткрывать в текущем виде. Если вы поняли вопрос и на него нет дубликата, приведите его во вменяемый вид и переоткройте, никто за это не банит.

> Ответ по ссылке дубликата не является ответом на поставленный вопрос Интерфейс и абстрактный класс они же получается ссылочные типы?

Мы не ставим цель дать буквально правильный ответ на любой вопрос, в том числе если ответ односложный и его легко найти в справочнике по языку.

> Модератор Grundy ведет себя странно. Или просто относится ко мне предвзято, он часто минусует меня и даже банил. Прошу снять с него модераторские права, или хотя-бы отправить в отпуск, этот беспредел уже надоел.

С чего вы взяли, что он относится предвзято? Дубликатами закрывается куча разных вопросов, не только тех, на которые вы отвечаете. За отправку в поисковики также банят всех в равной мере, [с незапамятных времен](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3922/), никто специально для вас этого не придумывал. За что снимать модераторские права, есть доказательства его нарушений?

> Я уже ранее писал в саппорт по этому поводу, меня отправили на Мету, вот я и пришел.

Отправка на Мету - это просто отписка. Здесь на Мете ни у кого нет возможности повлиять на модератора, кроме администратора, который и отвечает в той же форме саппорта. То есть вас вежливо послали лесом.

> Я конечно сразу не пошел, думал пройдет. Не прошло.

Что именно должно пройти? Если вы так же продолжаете отправлять авторов вопросов в поисковики, вас будут продолжать банить, так и должно быть. Это не простуда, само не пройдет. Соблюдайте правила, тогда проблемы не будет.

> До каких пор это будет продолжаться? У меня горит со страшной силой, хочется самоудалиться.

Это заявление не производит сильного впечатления, на фоне того, что предыдущий уход с сайта участника №1 по репутации закончился большим ничем. С сайта постоянно кто-то уходит и на их место приходят новые. Кстати, если вы удалитесь, ваши ответы останутся на сайте, но без вашего имени. Так что если надоело участвовать на сайте, лучше не удаляться, а просто забросить учетку.

Comment: `Так что если надоело участвовать на сайте, лучше не удаляться, а просто забросить учетку.` так и сделаю, спасибо за разбор, вроде се по делу.

Comment: Ну почему же сразу закончился ничем? У этого участника стало больше времени для нормальной жизни :-P

Answer (score 7):

Вторая часть вашего вопроса совершенно не связана с первой.  Уточните, ваш  вопрос о чем, о "неправильном" дубликате или о модераторских действиях? И если вопрос все же о первом, то было бы хорошо вначале привести тезис, а потом его аргументировать, а не из частного делать большие выводы.

---

Вопрос по ссылке неясен. Надо чтобы ТС уточнил, о чем же он все же спрашивает *".. для чего и что всё же?"*. Как минимум сейчас вопрос переоткрывать без правок не стоит (даже если он и не дубликат, имхо).

---

Теперь к значимой части:

- Минусовать может каждый и по любой причине - это часть механизма сайта. И это не наказуемо (кроме массовых случаев). Кто вас минусовал - неизвестно. Обвинять в этом кого-либо - некорректно.
- Конкретно по приведенному скриншоту - тянет на предупреждение как минимум.  Вы получали ранее предупреждения? Есть определенное правило, и оно вами нарушается (что и кристально ясно показано на скриншоте в 1 и 2 комментариях. 3й комментарий спорен). Достаточно ли этого для бана - вопрос открытый, т.к. у нас нет полной хронологии событий.
- Просьба снять модератора .. ничем не подтверждена. Модератор вас преследует .. как?
- > У меня горит со страшной силой, хочется самоудалиться.

  А вот это как раз признак того, что вам надо взять таймаут и остыть.

Comment: Я постарался привести пост в порядок, но мне ваш ответ неясен.

Comment: @aepot каков вопрос - таков ответ. Сейчас стало чуть яснее, что фокус на "предвзятости".

Comment: А @Kromster я вижу, во всех темах продолжает гипнотизировать . Модер, закрывает, блокирует, НО , все должны это мгновенно забыть и "не фокусироваться на личности модера" . Правильно ? Отличная мысль ! Модер приводит в первоначально состояние вопрос, ИЗВИНЯЕТСЯ публично за нанесенное оскорбление личному авторитету юзера. А потом все, на равных правах выясняют, кто прав, где ошибки, или где там рамка в вопросе не того цвета . Справедливо ?

Comment: А то я вижу, модеры — это либо божество местного масштаба, либо каста неприкасаемых, о которых либо хорошо, либо никак .