# Хотим ли мы всё-таки снять Grundy с поста модератора?

Tags: обсуждение, модераторский-произвол

На модератора **[@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/u/186999)** было много жалоб (и это только те, о которых написан пост на Мету, на самом деле их гораздо больше):

- 2021/12 - [Предвзятое отношение модератора к участнику RU SO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11830)
- 2022/02 - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11877
- 2022/12 - [Модератор чересчур рьяно закрывает вопросы. Не пора ли его снять?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12267)
- 2023/10 - [Но ведь это не дубликат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13087)

Напомню, что он регулярно закрывает вопросы, переоткрытые решением сообщества и/или других модераторов. Какие разделы справки и других правил модерации нарушает такое поведение, можно почитать [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12280).

Но все эти посты благополучно забыты. Поэтому давайте всё-таки окончательно решим этот вопрос, и, если решим, что Grundy надо снять, напишем на MSE (или как это [надо](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336173) делать).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151247/discussion-on-question-by-wchistow-------grundy---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer) или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Закрытие дубликатом вообще не требует полномочий модератора. Даже единоличное.

Comment: @Qwertiy, зато, насколько я знаю, эти полномочия требуются для многократного закрытия вопросов по одной и той же причине, чем Grundy и занимается.

Answer (score 24):

## Уволить

*Голосуйте "за" этот ответ, если вы согласны с тем, что Grundy надо уволить. Пожалуйста, не голосуйте "против" - вместо этого голосуйте "за" другой ответ.*

Comment: Мог бы просто создать 1 ответ. По голосам "за" и "против" поняли бы результат. А сейчас, [что это такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNxtA.png)?

Comment: @eccs0103 Думаю по "чистым" голосам "за" всё равно видно всё. Но да, странно получается)

Comment: Казнить нельзя помиловать

Comment: Нужен ещё пункт «я не голосую, мне только результат глянуть»

Comment: @VladD =>Я тоже об этом варианте думала 

Comment: _Как можно уволить того, кто и так не сотрудник? Никак._ Но на самом деле дело серьёзное. Имеем 27 голосов за снятие полномочий с модератора. В таком случае хотелось бы увидеть 27 вопросов на Мете от голосовавших со ссылкой на это голосование, в которых указано, какие именно нарушения допущены со стороны модератора, а так же выяснить, чем именно вас задел модератор. Пока вижу 4 примера за 3 года, один из них мой, где не предлагалось ничего ни с кого снимать. Хотелось бы подтвердить, что участники не просто нажимали кнопочку, а реально **прямо сейчас имеют обоснованные притензии к модератору**.

Comment: @aepot отлично сказано, прям бальзам на душу про претензии и хоть какие-то права нарушения, а то мусолят одно и тоже

Comment: @aepot 1. Предвзятое отношение лично ко мне (Может и к другим участникам тоже). 2. Свои приоритеты, выше приоритетов сообщества (Читайте "Модератор чересчур рьяно закрывает вопросы").

Comment: @aepot Ага, а вопросы закроют как дубликаты друг друга. ¬‿¬ Фигня это все. За "оставить" тоже могут нажимать механически, даже если никогда не взаимодействовали с этим модератором. Мои претензии вон в комментах (уже в чате) лежат.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat если мы здесь просто пошуметь, а не принимать какие-либо решения, то вопросов нет.

Comment: @aepot ?? Перефразирую. Если на английском SO устроят такой же бунт как здесь, но голосов за и против будет не +-20, а +-1000, вы бы тоже попросили 1000 уникальных вопросов от каждого голосующего? Количество голосов != количество уникальных "нарушений" модератора, а про одно и то же нарушение нет смысла плодить несколько постов. Даже одного крупного "нарушения" может быть достаточно для снятия.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat пожалуйста ссылку на "крупное нарушение" можно мне ?

Comment: @Dev18 Я не говорил, что оно есть, я сказал "может быть достаточно".

Comment: @Dev18 Кстати, поделитесь, вы Грундия вживую знаете?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я не смогла пройти мимо(признаю и это не всегда понимают/приветствуют, не надо было уведомление мне ставить на этот ЧЁРТОВ  вопрос и вообще каждый раз себя ругаю зачем я на мету КОГДА ТО зашла когда вижу такое... сидела себе на основном ресурсе)= , я просто решила открыть глаза тем кому их замылили, показать наглядно тех кто шумит, предупредить тех, кто сомневается а также возможно самой себе сказать ой Фарида ты не права увидев ссылку на "реальное нарушение" которую вы перевели на вопросом на вопрос и завуалировали основной сюжет

Comment: так, просто для информации: я на мете с апреля 2022 года (меньше двух лет), а на стекОверФлоу 6 с половиной лет, и мой вопрос реально был вопросом/тревогой, что могу потерять связь с русскоговорящим сообществом, сейчас конечно все уже научилась, но это я к тому,что с того момента, как я сюда пришла на мету имею ввиду, мне стыдно....да, прикиньте, пишут другие, а стыдно мне... вот история моего прихода на мету https://i.stack.imgur.com/gweq0.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsAvT.png

Comment: ща слышу, в след, тыыы тут 4 года с лишним была и так и не поняла, что такие вопросы тут не задают, у меня был шок, реально шок...(до этого что то меня останавливало, я в самом начале регистрации, когда "тур" прошла увидела мету/чаты, подумала, так мне сюда не надо, да и все равно я не задам такие вопросы не касающиеся программирования...)НО потом был такой шок(думаю как и у всех в мире), что я написала прям на основном сайте, не "по теме", и сразу удалила его...и потом заманилась сюда, и как дуб, порой ставлю эти уведомления, и потом видя грязь, не сдерживаюсь...

Comment: @Dev18, а вы всегда можете снять галочку "Отслеживается")

Comment: И всё-таки 
это +33/-10 не могло появится просто так, без причины.

Answer (score 15):

## Оставить

*Голосуйте "за" этот ответ, если вы согласны с тем, что Grundy надо оставить. Пожалуйста, не голосуйте "против" - вместо этого голосуйте "за" другой ответ.*

Answer (score 14):

## Нужно действовать!

У вас есть железные доказательства, из-за которых стоит снять с должности [Grundy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy)?

- Если да, то к чему вообще этот вопрос? Просто идите и пишите на основном сайте и там уже рассмотрят ваш запрос. Если хотите зарубиться поддержкой, то откройте и тут вопрос и уведомите других
- Если нет, то к чему вообще этот вопрос? Хотите побольше доказательств собрать? Очень плохую тактику выбрали

[Ещё тогда Kromster писал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12354/385375), но как-будто все прошли мимо

> - огорчает слабость текущего сформулированного поста, скудность прикрепленного материала и желтизна заголовка. За прошедшие недели особо ничего не поменялось, кроме диалогов в комментариях. Не такого качества тезиса и аргументации с доказательствами ожидаешь на Мете от участников с 10к+ репутации. Да и глупо, предлагать снятие по представленным 2 примерам (читай ниже).

Я вообще не понимаю такие вопросы. Вы читаете ответы участников, которые идут в кандидаты? [Вот ответы от Grundy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10791/385375)

> > Считаете ли вы себя подотчётным вашим избирателям? Возьмёте ли вы на себя дополнительные обязательства по отношению к ним, если станете модератором? Например, считаете ли вы для себя этически необходимым сложить полномочия, если вы по любым причинам не сможете выполнить то, что обещали перед выборами (хотя это формально и не требуется правилами)?
>
> Нет!

P.S. Если что лично у меня никаких претензий к [Grundy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) нет, меня всё устраивает

Какой смысл голосовать? В таких вопросах вообще нет смысла голосовать, это даже вредно чем полезно

Пусть `n` участников хотят, чтобы [Grundy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) покинул пост, а `m` нет. каким бы не было соотнешние `n` и `m` - это не доказывает ничего... Как это вообще может определять кто прав, а кто нет?

Сколько раньше людей убивали просто потому что была массовая истерия...

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151339/discussion-on-answer-by-eziomercer-------grundy---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer) или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 8):

Доказательная база слабовата. По ссылке в ответе insolor я вижу только ссылку на статью в блоге от 2009 г., написанную бывшим совладельцем компании, и притом облитым грязью за неполиткорректность. Она не имеет силы правил. Чтобы снять модератора, насколько я понимаю, нужно доказать нарушение либо норм поведения, либо модераторского соглашения. Тем, кто хочет снятия Grundy, надо привлекать толкового метаюриста, чтобы он нашел, какие пункты правил Grundy нарушил. И "Закрыл дубликатами много новичковых вопросов по JavaScript" явно не выглядит достаточным основанием.

Кроме того, по итогам прошлых конфликтов можно сказать, что вероятность снятия модератора по инициативе обычных участников довольно низкая. Последний случай - [в 2015 году](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1777/), и тогда шла речь о непристойных шутках про PHP-программистов + очень низкую модераторскую активность. Во время конфликтов 2018-2019 годов, когда участники жаловались на модератора за необоснованные баны, это закончилось ничем. Просто был ответ, что другие модераторы не увидели проблемы, а значит все хорошо. Если бы он другим модераторам или администрации дорогу перешел, или что-то неполиткоректное сказанул, вылетел бы мигом, а на проблемы простых пользователей всем плевать.

Comment: "Простые пользователи", когда становятся "бывалыми", порой согласны с данным модератором и даже... и даже порой говорят, что было сказано с горяча что то и когда то....Так что, речь идет о моментной вспышке эмоций...а еще добавлю, что приходит новый "недовольный/обиженный", видит, что ооо, этого админа уже "ругали" и "присоединяется"...тут еще есть человеческий фактор , которым многим не ясен и поэтому "старые обиженые хотят быть по человечески подкуплены"...ну как так то, ну почему он не извиняется, ну почему он с нами не "дружит"...

Comment: Вдогонку добавлю, что я вообще не голосовала тут, и умею не смешивать личное отношение, с объективной точкой зрения. Тем, кто "упоролся" скажу, что правда глаза когда колит, лучше умыться... Просто как и ответил выше отвечающий, (уже не)смешно/странно/и поднадоело "плодить/дублировать" вопросы на мете попусту про данного админа...

Comment: В общем, основная проблема явно обозначена. Это не ограниченный срок модераторства. Наверное **обязательные ежегодные перевыборы всех модераторов** решают ее

Comment: @avp для начала нужен хотя-бы один русскоговорящий КМ, закреплённый за сообществом, который может следить за работой модераторов, настроениями в сообществе, принимать такие решения как ежегодные перевыборы, обновлять правила, политики и т.д. К сожалению, без КМа мы не сможем обзавестись перевыборами или создать ещё что-либо отличающееся от процессов на остальных сайтах StackExchange.

Comment: @aepot мне почему-то казалось (и до сих пор кажется), что модераторы могут сами обращаться к администрации с какими-то инициативами, сообщать о необходимости выборов в том числе. Есть подозрение, что модераторов просто устраивает текущее положение дел, а участники - ну пошумят и разойдутся.

Comment: @insolor предложение инициативы регулярных выборов до администрации доводилось и обсуждалось неоднократно. В том числе пока Ник был КМом, ответ был отрицательный.