# Зачем голосовать за "Комментарии были перемещены в чат"?

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии, голоса-на-комментариях

Собственно нечего тут больше добавлять, просто хочу узнать мысли людей, которые голосуют за такие комментарии :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151361/discussion-on-question-by-eziomercer------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer) или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> просто хочу узнать мысли людей, которые голосуют за такие комментарии

ну тут, в данном вопросе мы уже двоих (из тех, кто поставил "лайк" именно за этот комментарий) услышали/прочитали, поэтому можно назвать это ответом

"...30 комментов висят, согласен, чтоб убрали"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а я могу от себя добавить, то, что и сказала в комментариях,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что причины могут быть разные, могу предположить, что даже наверно "случайно" можно ткнуть (за собой такого не припомню, это лишь предположение)

Comment: Удаляете если, то удаляйте полностью, а то теряете всю суть (кто сказал, когда сказал, зачем сказал, и так далее). Да и другое отношение к одному из участников, ну, это странно. Все цитаты вдруг со скринами, а мой удалили. Ну а отдельное отношение ко мне, я тогда против размещения моих комментариев в вашем ответе (раз они вам стали вдруг неугодны).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ   (символы, для отправки коммента)

Answer (score 2):

Расскажу нечастую ситуацию, когда эти голоса действительно имеют смысл.

Я иногда при переносе комментариев восстанавливал часть перенесённых комментариев, которые считал существенными. Естественно, сообщение про чат последнее. Если восстановить слишком много комментариев, то последние не показываются. Вообще, я старался избегать таких ситуаций, но если они всё же возникали, то голос за комментарий о переносе (а может несколько) помогает оставить этот комментарий видимым, а скрыть какой-нибудь другой с меньшим числом голосов. Впрочем, за свои комменты голосовать нельзя)

Comment: При "переносе" комментариев можно ведь не ставить галку "удалять комментарии", и просто почистить лишние, когда "перенос" (фактически, "копирование") в чат уже произведено.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ну обычно удалять больше, чем оставлять, поэтому проще поставить)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, речь идет об [этом вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13188/324730).

### Уточним

> просто хочу узнать мысли людей, которые голосуют за такие комментарии :)

Предполагаю, что люди голосуют не просто за такие комментарии, а за такие комментарии **от участника [@Grundy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186999)**. Прощу обратить внимание на то, что аналогичный авто-комментарий под [ответом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13196/) в той же ветке, но от другого модератора не имеет голосов:

> [image]

> [image]

### Почему?

Опять же предпологаю, что факт того, что вопрос обсуждающий конкретного участника, где участник участвует лишь тем, что переносит комментарии в чат могло казаться кому-то забавным. ¯\*(o_O)*/¯

---

Я сам не голосовал, и это всего лишь мое предположение.

Comment: `Думаю, речь идет об этом вопросе` - речь ни о каком вопросе, я это встречаю достаточно не редко