Блокировка доступа ко всей очереди проверок из-за голосования в пользу переоткрытия вопроса: обоснованное действие или произвол?
Здравствуйте участники сообщества и модераторы!
Недавно мне, как и возможно другим участникам, был заблокирован доступ к очередям проверок после голосования за переоткрытие вопроса, ранее закрытого модератором. Вопрос за который мы голосовали, касался асинхронного вызова функций в JavaScript и необходимости передать данные из одной функции в другую после завершения запроса. Тема была закрыта модератором как дубликат, но несколько участников, включая меня, посчитали что закрытие было преждевременным.

Однако, несмотря на множество голосов за переоткрытие, вопрос так и не был пересмотрен, и вместо этого мне и возможно остальным был выставлен бан на всю очередь проверок. Причина указывается как "некорректная проверка", что по моему мнению несправедливо.
Мне бы хотелось, чтобы модератор объяснил свое решение, особенно учитывая голоса сообщества за переоткрытие.

Большое количество участников проголосовало за переоткрытие, основываясь возможно на субъективном, но всё же мнении о полезности обсуждаемого вопроса. Блокировка доступа к очередям проверок создает впечатление, что выбор участников игнорируется, а единственно верным является мнение модератора, а кто с ним не согласен идёт в бан?!

Прошу пересмотреть блокировку доступа к очередям проверок для голосовавших за переоткрытие и объяснить причины закрытия данного вопроса.
P.S. Один, два


Будьте более радикальным. Требуйте вообще перестать закрывать вопросы (кроме откровенного бреда или полного несоответствия IT)

Вот это я понимаю — основных "игроков", которые занимаются правками, их принятием, открытием и закрытием вопросов/ответов, "выбивают" из игры. Требую ввести метку [tag:Разборки]!

Закрытый вопрос явно кого-то задел за живое. Чтобы доступ ограничивать всем, это прям перегиб. Я ещё могу понять, чтобы оставить вопрос закрытым, но чтобы ограничивать права пользователей...

Лол, вот что я нашёл по метке [tag:модераторский-произвол], прям первый вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13188/

"Я медленно снимаю с себя ромб..."

@Chaos_Sower, туда же в коллекцию: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12267/1365

@Amgarak меня тоже вчера заблокировали. Правда потом сообщение куда-то делось, и я всё смог нормально проверять.

Интересно, по старой доброй традиции таких вопросов, сколько времени пройдет до перемещения комментариев в чат(виновником данного вопроса)?

@avp, здесь явно имеет место радикальность другого рода со стороны известного модератора.  Выходит, если Grundy уже закрыл вопрос как дубликат, то как бы автор вопроса не пытался его отредактировать и доказать, что это "не дубликат", это полностью бессмысленно.  А чтобы всякие невежественные проверяльщики "автокликеры" (но не все!) не голосовали за переоткрытие таких вопросов, закрытых Большой Круглой Печатью, и вообще очистили от своего присутствия очереди проверок -- их загоняют в стойло.

@aepot, сколько голосов модераторов требуется для принятия решения по бану?  достаточно одного голоса?

@NowhereMan мы не голосуем по банам. Но неоднозначные ситуации конечно обсуждаются.

@SwaD система при достижении 20 комментариев под сообщением за короткий промежуток времени ставит на него автоматическую тревогу.

Хотим ли мы всё-таки снять Grundy с поста модератора?

While we understand that there is some frustration and questions about potential moderator misconduct, historically, the Community Team manages a process for handling formal complaints against moderators. For this reason, if you have concerns about moderators' actions, we encourage you to use the "Contact Us" option so we can properly investigate and utilize this process if necessary.
We value privacy in these situations, so there won't be any public announcements regarding outcomes or whether a conduct review has been initiated.
Additionally, while it's perfectly okay to use Meta for discussing moderator actions, we are noticing that the current conversation might not be as productive as it could be. As such, we kindly ask moderators to lock this post temporarily and appreciate your patience as we investigate further.

Я не верю, что Amgarak использовал автокликер, и он сам открыто заявил, что этого не делал. Я не раз видела его правки и комментарии — как автокликер может реагировать и писать? Сообщество имеет право защищать своих участников, если их действия ошибочно интерпретируются или необоснованно подвергаются обвинениям. Нам крайне важно получить официальный ответ и разъяснение ситуации, чтобы восстановить справедливость и не допустить повторения подобных инцидентов.
Несправедливое отношение к активным членам сообщества неприемлемо!!!
Эта ситуация требует обязательного внимания. В наших правилах указано, что сообщество имеет право выражать свою позицию и обращаться к администрации, если действия модераторов не соответствуют нормам. Мы, как сообщество, должны иметь право высказываться, особенно когда возникают вопросы о том, насколько решения модераторов согласуются с правилами и здравым смыслом.
Более того, недавно обсуждался аналогичный случай: Nowhere Man также получил блокировку, несмотря на его активное участие в проверке правок и помощь новичкам (принять и править). Логично ли, что человек, якобы использующий автокликер, одновременно столь вовлечен в улучшение качества контента? Автокликер, который выполняет такую осмысленную работу, — это технически нереально и абсурдно. Этот случай поднимает вопросы об объективности и последовательности решений.
Призываю всех модераторов собраться на «совет» и обсудить эту ситуацию, чтобы дать четкий ответ сообществу. Ваше мнение имеет большое значение, и каждый из вас может внести ясность, которая укрепит доверие участников и обеспечит справедливую модерацию. Вас семеро, и ваше совместное решение будет воспринято с большим уважением.
Мы надеемся на ваше внимание к данной ситуации. Если модераторы продолжат игнорировать обращения, мы будем вынуждены обратиться в офис с коллективным письмом. Это может негативно отразиться на всех участниках, поскольку администрация может решить, что сообщество не способно решать внутренние вопросы, и примет более строгие меры. Давайте решать вопросы внутри сообщества, ценить участников, поддерживать волонтерство и добрые инициативы.
Кроме того, я призываю модераторов не только дать ясный ответ, но и рассмотреть возможность изменения истории несправедливой блокировки, чтобы восстановить моральное состояние тех, кого затронула эта ситуация. Нам не вернуть потерянное время, но честное признание и внесение корректировок могли бы восполнить моральный ущерб и вернуть уверенность сообществу в справедливости и открытости модерации.
Nofate♦, Nick Volynkin♦, Qwertiy♦, ЮрийСПб♦, Grundy♦, αλεχολυτ♦, aepot♦, пожалуйста, обратите ваше внимание на данный пост. Прошу.

Что за минус?! Отличный ответ! Жаль вы не участвовали в выборах модераторов... (интересно, а там есть порог по репутаци?)

Думаю бан не за автокликер, а за "посмел проголосовать не так, как его величество модератор", просто сообщение бана одинаковое.

@Chaos_Sower, если бы знали, как дорого мне это дается, вы бы не писали этого (я бы очень хотела, быть в тени, но порой я оказываюсь на виду, сама непонимаю как). Я настолько застенчивая настолько же справедливая...это очень сложно пройти мимо несправедливости. Любой бы так поступил думаю. ТС и другие затронутые участники получили несправедливую блокировку, это больно и некрасиво. Там семь модераторов, я верю (хочу верить) в них.

да, шутку Амгарака про "автокликер" похоже оценили по достоинству..

@Chaos_Sower "(интересно, а там есть порог по репутации?)" — для голосования надо 150, для выдвижения 300 (пруф: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1984/532877)

@Зонтик, я только вчера об этом сам узнал)) Но вы молодец, что скинули ссылку :)

@Chaos_Sower я понял, что вы не знали, поэтому и ответил)
