# Удаление комментариев с заданными словами по первой тревоге

Tags: поддержка, комментарии, тревоги

Согласно доступным статистическим данным, можно говорить, что сообщество Stack Overflow на русском является крайне культурным сообществом по отношению к плохим вопросам и их авторам: мы голосуем против, закрываем или вовсе удаляем такие вопросы, но никогда  (возможно, за редким исключением) не оскорбляем авторов! Для нас, сообщества, это крайне важно, так как «культурное» отношение к «слабым вопросам» дает возможность создать и поддерживать атмосферу знаний и включения на сайте. Новые участники могут отбросить ненужные эмоции и сконцентрироваться на главном – на своем вопросе к коллегам.

[image]
<sub>Отношение количества тревог типа «оскорбление или спам» к общему количеству комментариев.</sub>

Подобного уровня взаимного уважения в сообществе невозможно добиться без своевременной коллективной модерации сайта. Все же случается, что явно [«лишние» комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2349/) остаются без соответствующей реакции сообщества. Возможно, это происходит в связи с неоднозначностью некоторых комментариев, возможно, иногда подобное поведение становится результатом временного возрастания вопросов низкого качества.

Для того чтобы помочь сообществу в борьбе с неуместными комментариями, в движке сайта был добавлен (достаточно давно) специальный механизм автоматического удаления комментариев в случае, если комментарий удовлетворяет заданному шаблону (содержит определенное слово или фразу) и любой участник отметил комментарий любым типом тревоги. Данный функционал был добавлен специально для быстрого удаления спама, нецензурной лексики и других выражений «исключающей лексики», например, фраз вида «Гуглить не пробовал?» без каких–либо дополнительных пояснений.

Насколько мне известно, данный функционал ранее не использовался у нас на сайте. Что я поспешил исправить!

> #### Коротко
>
> Если комментарий будет содержать любое слово из запрещенного набора, одной тревоги от любого участника будет достаточно для автоматического удаления комментария.

#### Более развернуто

Узнав о наличии описанной выше возможности, я поспешил составить список так называемых «стоп–слов». Для этого я создал очень простое приложение ([код на GitHub](https://github.com/chabanovsky/flag_words)). Основная идея заключается в следующем:

1. С внутренней версии SEDE я выгрузил:

   - [комментарии](https://github.com/chabanovsky/flag_words/blob/master/comments.csv), которые были удалены как спам или оскорбительные;
   - хорошие [вопросы](https://github.com/chabanovsky/flag_words/blob/master/questions.csv) и [ответы](https://github.com/chabanovsky/flag_words/blob/master/answers.csv).
2. Составил список всех слов, используемых в комментариях.
3. Составил список всех слов, используемых в вопросах и ответах.
4. Из списка слов из комментариев вычел список слов вопросов и ответов. Получил [список уникальных для «оскорбительных» комментариев слов](https://github.com/chabanovsky/flag_words/blob/master/result.csv).
5. Вручную удалил из списка обычные слова, получив [список](https://github.com/chabanovsky/flag_words/blob/master/processed_list.csv), используемый в настройке сайта.

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что настройки сайта выполнены в качестве регулярного выражения, которое в текущей реализации проверяет на вхождение всего слова. При желании мы можем изменить регулярное выражение в будущем, собрав список корней стоп–слов.

Конечно, я понимаю, что у данного подхода существуют серьезные ограничения: чтобы обидеть человека, ругательные слова не нужны, можно с легкостью оттолкнуть от решения проблем в сообществе и обычными словами. Идея проста: мы по–прежнему полностью доверяем мнению участников, а не «машине». Данный механизм носит лишь вспомогательную роль для более динамичного удаления нежелательных комментариев. Итоговое решение все равно остается на совести участников, управляющих содержанием нашей общей базы знаний.

Буду рад услышать отзывы и рекомендации как по улучшению приложения для создания стоп–слов, так и о самой функции удаления по одной тревоге в ответах и комментариях к этому вопросу.

Comment: "4 Из списка слов из комментариев вычел список слов вопросов и ответов. Получил [список уникальных для «оскорбительных» комментариев слов](https://github.com/chabanovsky/flag_words/blob/master/result.csv)." - **василийбарбашев**  был бы недоволен сим фактом :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Поправил. Просто совпадение.

Comment: Спасибо. Пополнил свой запас ругательных слов)

Comment: По такому списку пока рано. Как минимум из него надо исключить имена реальных участников (а их там хватает), разметку (там попадаются `**` по краям слов) и пересмотреть записи латиницей (их не так много, но почти все из списка надо выкинуть). И даже после этого останется много слов, которые там быть не должны.

Comment: @D-side, видимо, вы смотрите не тот файл. Итоговый список [стоп–слов](https://github.com/chabanovsky/flag_words/blob/master/processed_list.csv) я получил на шаге 5.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky это ручная работа, неинтересно :) Да, вручную составленный список будет работать, разумеется. Но возможно, его можно ещё улучшить силами автоматики.

Comment: Вы не пробовали в существующую программу по отсеву спама скормить комментарии? Для обучения системы "плохие" комментарии уже помечены, в качестве "хороших", можно комментарии с положительными голосами использовать, часть всех комментариев для тестов можно оставить — система может даже обучаться постоянно (маленький плюс, если тревогу выставили для комментария помеченного системой (система сработала) и большой большой минус, если плюс поставили на комментарий (система ошиблась, "false positive"). Для этого даже [naive Bayes filtering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_spam_filtering).

Comment: ..может сработать. Или взять готовую библиотеку по машинному обучению с более сложными методами и посмотреть какие из них будут работать на (относительно) малом объёме данных из Stack Overflow. Главное что много комментариев уже классифицированы — тяжёлая работа сделана.

Comment: А "устаревшие комментарии" у вас также к "плохим" относятся? Нормальный комментарий может быть помечен устаревшим, если к примеру ответ поправили.

Comment: @jfs На сколько я знаю, в той функции, что мы активировали (для которой я искал стоп–слова), нет машинного обучения. На сколько я понимаю (в код не смотрел), она работает следующим образом. Когда участник оставляет тревогу на комментарий, присходит проверка регулярным выражением текста комментария. Если выражение возвращает совпадение, то система автоматически удаляет комментарий.

Comment: @jfs  Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я понял ваш комментарий?

Comment: 1- Отвечаю на свой вопрос из последнего комментария (невнимательно читал вопрос): "устаревшие" комментарии не относятся к категории оскорбительных.  2- про naive Bayes я упомянул, чтобы  "плохие" комментарии собрать со всего набора, а не только явно помеченных вручную. Я имел в виду что-то простое на коленке из готовых частей по быстрому собрать, чтобы все комментарии на сайте обработать и выдрать список слов. Это одна часть.

Comment: Был вдохновлён: [Can a machine be taught to flag spam automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301) (но это заметно больше усилий)

Comment: @jfs Основная проблема любых фильтров, в том числе, что получился в этом приложении – люди оскорбляют других людей комбинацией вполне обычных слов. То есть надо действительно что–то сложное придумывать, а потом еще и способ проверки на сайте менять, так как учесть падежи, склонения, различную последовательность слов и тд будет крайне сложно. У нас только вариаций на тему гуглить/загуглить/погуглить/нагуглить можно с десяток, вероятно, придумать. Очень сложно получается, если делать что–либо большее, чем то, что есть сейчас, к сожалению.

Comment: `"лень","лентяй","за тебя"` - я бы не вносил в список.

Comment: @Qwertiy +, для контекста я иногда даю подсказку-почти-ответ в комментариях, а когда она приводит ТСа к ответу, признаюсь, что "мне лень писать ответ" и не обижусь, если ТС напишет ответ сам :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Пожалуйста, опишите причины такого решения подробно!

Answer (score 13):

Мне решительно не нравится идея удаления без разбора при вхождении слова "гугл". Комментарий "попробуй загуглить то-то то-то" — корректный, но некоторых участников может раздражать, так как не содержит явного ответа, только наводку для самостоятельного разбора. Ключевые слова бывают очень важны. Хотелось бы избежать ложных срабатываний. Туда же "за тебя".

Comment: Минус мой. [Хорошо понимаю логику](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/213987) с обеих сторон: это как в ресторане вышвыривать приходящих со словами "голоден -- иди жри дома!" Если вопрос тематичен, но примитивен -- это не повод его не задавать, у всех людей разные представления о том, что примитивно, а что нет. С другой стороны хорошо понимаю эгалитарный снобизм тех, кто не первый год сидит на ресурсе и простые вопросы надоели. Не нравится -- мимокрокодил, но не надо при этом в комментах унижать спрашивающего и отправлять в гугл/доки и т.п.

Comment: @AK предложение что-то погуглить может быть не первой реакцией на вопрос, а появиться в ходе обсуждения. Перекинулись десятком комментариев и отвечающий предлагает "возможно стоит погуглить про X".

Comment: @Nofate Логично. Тогда вопрос. Это частая ситуация или скорее умозрительная, что _могут_ флагануть через десяток комментариев? Вы как модератор уже сталкивались с подобным?

Comment: @AK флагают повсеместно

Comment: Верное ли замечание – увидим со временем. Можно вернуться к этому вопросу через, к примеру, три месяца и посмотреть список удаленных комментариев. В общем случае, все же, [лучше давать качественный развернутый ответ, а не просить «погуглить что–то» в комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/).

Answer (score 4):

По-моему отличная идея.

Ещё бы первые сообщения из серии "я думаю что это форум, как мне сделать мега-сайт, подскажите?" по аналогичной методе фильтровать. По такой же вряд ли получится, конечно.

Comment: Обязательно посмотрю на наличие данной возможности в движке. Вроде бы какая–то фильтрация есть на Stack Overflow на английском, возможно что–то получится подкрутить и для русского языка.