# Автоматическое удаление комментариев по тревоге «более не является необходимым»

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, комментарии

Продолжая улучшать соотношение сигнал–шум в нашей базе знаний, предлагаю автоматизировать удаление комментариев по тревоге «более не является необходимым». Мы уже знакомы с механикой работы этой функции сайта (см. «[Удаление комментариев с заданными словами по первой тревоге](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5899/)»), но повторюсь очень кратко:

1. Участник сообщества может оставить тревогу «более не является необходимым» для комментария под вопросом или ответом.
2. Комментарии с тревогами попадают в специальную очередь для проверки модератором сообщества.
3. Модераторы вручную проверяют комментарии из очереди и либо подтверждают тревогу и удаляют комментарий, либо отклоняют тревоги — и комментарий остается на сайте.

Проблема обнаружилась во время обсуждения вопроса «[Отклонены тревоги "более не является необходимым" и другие казусы модерации комментариев](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7046/)» — на сайте очень много комментариев, которые следовало бы удалить как «более не является необходимым», но сил текущей команды модераторов для этого недостаточно. Это становится явно видно уже при первом приближении. Запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM PostComments c
WHERE lower(c.Text) LIKE N'%спасибо%' AND c.DeletionDate IS NULL;
```

говорит, что у нас есть 73 тысячи неудаленных комментариев со словом «спасибо».

#### Автоматизация удаления

Движок сайта дает возможность задать набор стоп–слов. Если одно из этих стоп–слов присутствует в комментарии и комментарий будет отмечен тревогой «более не является необходимым», то он будет удален системой автоматически, без добавления в очередь проверки для модераторов.

Для создания списка стоп–слов я написал [простое консольное приложение](https://github.com/chabanovsky/most-common-in-no-longer-needed), загрузил [комментарии с тревогой «более не является необходимым»](https://github.com/chabanovsky/most-common-in-no-longer-needed/blob/master/comments.csv) и получил следующую строку настройки сайта для наиболее часто встречающихся 50 слов:

> `вопрос[ов|а|ы|ом|у|e]*|ответ[ов|а|ы|ом|у|e]*|спасибо|код[а]*|комментари[и|й]*`

Уверен, что это далеко не исчерпывающий список и его необходимо будет расширить в будущем. Пожалуйста, отмечайте не являющиеся более необходимыми комментарии тревогой! Мы будем следить за статистикой и обновлять настройку для автоматического удаления (сейчас в базе всего семь сотен комментариев с этой тревогой). Если у вас есть идеи о других стоп–словах, которые можно добавить уже сейчас, пожалуйста, напишите об этом!

Comment: 1. Если это регулярное выражение, то оно неверное. 2. Хватит уже удалять всё подряд.

Comment: @Qwertiy Это регулярное выражение и вроде бы работает. Если вы видите ошибку, пожалуйста, дайте знать где, я обязательно поправлю. Если вы считаете эту или другую инициативу не верной, пожалуйста, опубликуйте *развернутый ответ–пояснение* вашей позиции.

Comment: 1. Скобки должны быть круглые, а не квадратные. 2. Звёздочки должны быть вопросами.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я вижу проблему как минимум в том, что большаяя часть комментариев, которые вы использовали для статистики, устарела не из-за "спасибо", а из-за изменения контекста. т.е. комментарии вида "оформите коммент выше ответом" устаревают не потому, что в них есть слово "ответ", а потому, что кто-то действительно оформил новый ответ. то же самое с "код", "вопрос" и "комментарий". если задача - фильтровать именно "спасибо" - хватило бы "спасибо" + фильтр по длине (чтобы под него попадало "Большое спасибо!!!" и "спасибо, +1"

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky т.е. фильтр должен быть таким, чтобы он сносил по тревоге комментарии, которые вообще не стоило бы оставлять. и не допускал злоупотреблений вида "нажал на "мне этот ответ не подошел", т.к. считают что ответ нормальный" - и сайт его молча снес.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky в качестве прямого примера - если ваш фильтр включить, то *любой* участник может взять и снести ваш коммент с тремя плюсами выше. и мои комментарии заодно. без уведомлений, фильтрации и модерации. просто потому, что этот участник посчитает, что вашему комменту на сайте больше не место.

Comment: @PashaPash Постарался развернуто пояснить идеи в [ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7105/6). Буду рад вашему комментарию.

Comment: Опубликовал отчет за первые две недели инициативы: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7155/6

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7197/207618

Comment: Ложное срабатывание: ^^^

Comment: Есть предложение по продуктивному сужению и конкретизации целевой группы вашей идеи: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44258474#44258474, https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44258666#44258666.

Comment: Вот ещё идея дополнить/заменить понятие «техзадание» на «отсутствие обмена опытом»: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44254369#44254369, https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44260038#44260038.

Comment: Мне таки интересно, на каком-таком языке/стандарте записана эта регулярка. Память выдаёт что похожее, связанное с перлом... Но вряд ли.

Comment: Слова типа "Благодарю" и его производные, возможно, есть смысл добавить в список.

Answer (score 14):

### Слаженность людей и "автоматики"

Во-первых, очень бы хотелось понимание у модераторов почему следует удалять такого рода комментарии. Блестящая, на мой взгляд, аргументация приведена в [ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7052/220571), где также упомянуто о соответствии правилам.

Хотелось бы также среди модераторов понимания, что их работа должна основываться на правилах сообщества, а не их личных мнениях, если они противоречат правилам. Это было бы полезно для работы данной автоматизации, так как будет некорректно если очевидные комментарии будут автоматически удаляться, а что-то более сложное — нет. "Автоматика" и модераторы должны работать слаженно.

### Точность срабатывания

На мой взгляд, наличие срабатывания по регулярному выражению

> `вопрос[ов|а|ы|ом|у|e]*|ответ[ов|а|ы|ом|у|e]*|спасибо|код[а]*|комментари[и|й]*`

неудачная идея и дело, возможно, даже не в самой регулярке. Чтобы избежать ложных срабатываний должен проверяться **весь текст комментария**, а не наличие какого-то слова. Я могу ошибаться, но здесь просто ищется наличие слов "вопрос", "ответ", "спасибо", "код", "комментарий" и их падежей. Могу привести кучу примеров комментариев, которые будут ложными срабаниями данной регулярки:

- Оценка комментария

  > Комментарий участинка X неверен, так как…
- Благодарность + замечание

  > Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, но ваш код содержит синтаксическую ошибку на строке…
- Оценка ответа

  > А чем ваш ответ отвечается от ответа X?
- Упоминание вопроса

  > Связанный вопрос…

На мой взгляд, нужно удалять только очевидные вещи, которым точно не место.

### Что же удалять

Автоматика должна удалять без ошибок, иначе смысла в ней нет, поэтому следует смотреть весь комментарий и сверять его полностью на соответствие простым шаблонам. Можно потом снова слепить из этого регулярку, но я говорю сразу, что указываю примеры **всего** комментария, а не подстроки. Поэтому лично вижу совсем небольшой список (который, возможно, было бы лучше рассмотреть отдельным вопросом):

- > Большое спасибо
- > Огромное спасибо
- > Cпасибо большое
- > Спасибо огромное
- > Пожалуйста

и подобного рода простых вариаций, которые будут периодически вноситься, если будут встречаться модераторам часто. Проверку следует сделать нечувствительную к регистру и в конце нужно проверить на факультативный восклицательный знак и точку `[!.]?`.

### Существующие комменатарии

Считаю также, что было бы верно, чтобы существующие комментарии также бы удалялись при внесении новых паттернов, что сильно упростило бы жизнь модераторам. Но выбор паттерна должен быть очень внимательным и скрупулёзным.

Comment: Хоть (как участник) я и против удаления - поддерживаю в той части, что регексы и вообще удаление по наличию одного слова - не слишком надежное решение.

Comment: Я бы выкинул все небуквы, а потом уже проверял бы на точное соответствие без учета регистра

Answer (score 12):

В рамках особого мнения по вопросу.

> TL;DR
>   Комментарии - важная часть сайта Q & A.
>
> Удалять можно только при полном совпадении фразы с запрещённой,
>   никакие регулярные выражения недопустимы.

Я поддерживаю позицию тех участников, кто считает, что нельзя (полу)автоматически удалять комментарии по регэспу. Мы не строим атомную электростанцию и я вполне доверяю автоматике, но я предпочитаю, чтобы удалялись только гарантированно бесполезные сообщения. И я понимаю, что эффективность решения будет заведомо ниже, чем у регулярок. Но если на мой взгляд комментарии типа "спасибо" не особо мешают - меня лично не сильно напрягает, что только 34% таких комментариев будет удаляться автоматически, а не 43%: самим себе создать проблему "как удалить комментарий автоматически", чтобы потом из-за этой рукотворной проблемы получить следующий вал проблем "а как разобраться с некорректным удалением". Да никак не надо: не стоило и подымать вопрос о удалении по регулярке.

Однако я просто поставил апвоут и пошёл дальше, а к написанию особого мнения меня подтолкнул пост Николаса.

Основное несогласие с высказанной точкой зрения: комментарии - это важная часть Q & A сайта и я не хочу, чтобы руководство сообществом продолжало думать в направлении "так давайте же вообще комментарии удалим". Я слышал, были подобные предложения  о преобразовании комментариев в "уточнения к вопросу" и если подобная вещь когда-либо станет реальностью - для меня ценность stackoverflow как платформы резко упадёт и я вряд ли продолжу ей пользоваться.

Мне решительным образом не нравится, когда из рассмотрения убирают комментарии к ответу и сводят роль комментариев исключительно к "уточнениям к вопросу". Да, есть такая роль у комментариев - но только исключительно к ней сводить считаю вредным самообманом. Как только декларируется цепочка комментарии равно уточнение -> *не нужны* я понимаю, что мне только что попытались продать заведомо некорректную идеологию.

> Комментарии - это обратная связь.

В противовес мнению Николаса, который считает комментарии злом, проистекающим из несовершенства мира я буду говорить исключительно о пользе комментариев. Просто в противовес, чтобы создалась полная картина, а не потому что я не согласен с его мнением (в той позиции есть много полезных и правильных мыслей, скажем, концепт "информационного шума", я не собираюсь полностью отрицать)

Я хочу напомнить о том, что комментарии бывают не только к вопросу, но и к ответу - и эти комментарии зачастую обладают огромной ценностью. Многие ответы, особенно на SOen обросли таким количеством комментариев, где раскрывается ограниченность предложенного решения и краевые условия, что на таких комментариях стоит не меньше апвоутов, чем на самом ответе!

Я затрудняюсь, как можно было бы без слов достигнуть такого эффекта. Представьте, что у вас всего пара стрелочек и пара смайликов - и попробуйте выразить с этой помощью мысли вида:

- не работает в .net core
- в версии ХХ фреймворка также потребуется

и так далее, примеров масса.

При помощи комментариев двух авторов ответа можно устроить очную ставку решений, а вы как читатель спустя годы имеете более широкие возможности поприсутствовать на этой дискуссии и посмотреть результаты.

Поэтому я высказывал свою позицию именно к тому, чтобы у владельцев платформы не складывалось впечатления, что комментарии несут исключительный вред и их терпят лишь до поры до времени:

- если в дискуссиях меня будут просить отвечать строго по заявленному вопросу (удалять/не удалять)
- и если администрация при этом будет ненавязчиво продвигать более широкую точку зрения (при этом - однобокую)

То я вполне представляю, что через некоторое время сайт возможно окажется завален тоннами высказываний только одного вида "комментарии не нужны" (а письменных свидетельств противоположного вида не будет) и возникнет желание их удалить. А без комментариев система будет обессушена.

Не трогайте пожалуйста комментарии, не надо.

Comment: Соглашусь, что не все комментарии необходимо удалять. Это реальный мир. Но никто и не предлагает удалять все подряд! Предлагается удалить комментарии аналогичные тем, что приведены в примере вывода программы. Я не могу понять, в чем ценность комментария «суперответ! зачот!», если ответ принят. Я сам лично сталкивался с ситуацией, когда ответ был принят, имел самый большой рейтинг из всех ответов, а в комментарии говорилось, что он не верный и имеет проблемы с безопасностью, с пояснением почему это так. Такие комментарии, конечно, удалять не стоит.

Comment: Давайте рассмотрим проблему на реальных данных, чтобы было ясно, где закралась потенциальная ошибка! Если у вас есть время, вы можете привести контр примеры с помощью [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/edit/835600).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky контрпримеры легко найти дописав к запросу `order by len(c.Text) desc`

Answer (score 10):

Поддерживаю инициативу, но хотелось бы чуть-чуть больше контроля и проверки. А то щас кто-нибудь ломанется удалять всё подряд, не разбираю где "спасибо" шум, а где одно из 120 слов ценного комментария.

Нужно голоса хотя бы от пары независимых людей (с репутацией от 1000) "за" удаление. Какие есть возможности для этого?

Answer (score 8):

## Автоматическое удаление не нужно.

Обсуждение есть с вопросе [Зачем нам удаление комментариев со "спасибо"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7097/178988).

1. Велика вероятность false positive - полезные комментарии смогут удаляться довольно беспричинно. Почему-то мы даже для закрытия вопроса на неправильном языке [требуем 5 голосов, а не 1](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5509/178988), а тут вдруг захотелось автоматизации?
2. Да и вообще удаление этих комментариев сомнительно, потому что они ближе к галочке, чем к плюсу - комментарий "спасибо, помогло" - это знак, что человеку не просто понравился ответ, а он его реально применил на практике и решение работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, давайте придерживаться стандартной модели Stack Overflow: одна проблема - один вопрос.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ну хватит уже объявлять всё дубликатами. Там про удаление в принципе, а тут - только про автоматическое. Это не дубликаты.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Всё-таки несмотря на несогласие с позицией Qwertiy по его обсуждению, я тоже считаю что это не дубликат.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, а за переоткрытие проголосовать не хочешь?

Comment: @Qwertiy Проголосовал.

Comment: @Qwertiy Как вы можете заметить, в данном вопросе есть и про удаление в принципе, и про идеологию комментариев и про автоматику. Ко всему, вопрос–дубликат состоит только из опроса да/нет. Если у вас есть мысли по удалению комментариев, в том числе в общем, пожалуйста, опубликуйте развернутый ответ в этом вопросе. Ответ в виде «Я создал еще один вопрос, давайте проголосуем в нем» выглядит крайне неоднозначно и дробит знания сообщества о проблеме.

Comment: @Qwertiy Но если честно, в том вопросе я не вижу хоть какого-то смысла. Вряд ли что-то изменится от результатов голосования.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, нет, я не вижу, что в этом вопросе есть про удаление в принципе.

Answer (score 5):

Предположу, что простого наличия стоп-слова в комментарии может быть недостаточно для того, чтобы считать комментарий шумом, требующим удаления. Стоит задаться неким процентом наличия стоп-слов в комментарии от общей его длины, это позволит оставить более сложные фразы для ручного анализа модераторами. Ну и на удаляемое «спасибо» хорошо бы как-то удалять и последующие «пожалуйста», иначе они будут довольно странно смотреться.

Есть еще мысль, о том, как бороться с ложно удалёнными (т.е. такие, которое не стоило бы удалять автоматически) комментариями. Правда это потребует довольно серьёзного изменения доступа, и может быть, стоить оформить отдельным предложением (feature-request) на MSE. Суть в том, чтобы давать участникам с достаточной репутацией возможность просмотра удалённых комментариев. Сейчас такая возможность есть только у модераторов, но можно ограничить её исключительно комментариями, удалёнными автоматикой. Когда участник с достаточной репутацией видит такой комментарий у него есть возможность отметить его тревогой для последующего восстановления (может и вовсе восстановить самостоятельно или голосованием). Окончательное удаление может наступать либо по таймауту бездействия с этим комментарием, либо путём дополнительного подтверждения участником. Всё это должно уменьшить вероятность потери полезных комментариев.

Answer (score 4):

### tl;dr: Нужно исключить из автообработки тревоги для модераторов.

---

Безотносительно моего мнения об этой затее в целом, считаю необходимым обратить внимание на одну важную проблему с этим механизмом:

#### Сейчас он не обращает внимания на причину тревоги.

В частности, он перехватывает тревоги **и для модераторов**. Которые оставляются специально для того, чтобы пояснение прочитал модератор и принял (или не принял) меры **в соответствии с пояснением**.

К великому сожалению, "Тревогообработчик-9000" читать естественный язык ещё не научился, посему предлагаю ему научиться **пропускать** тревоги с особыми пояснениями. Потому что ему невдомёк, что может быть нужно стереть целую *цепочку* комментариев сразу (не все из которых могут подходить под регулярку), или вообще ничего стирать не надо т. к. проблема не в этом. Или, например, что тревога связана с сообщением, на которое оставить тревогу нельзя.

Comment: Здорово, а если возможно, то можно и ограничиться одной причиной, той, что в заголовке вопроса.

Comment: @vp_arth ну... Вообще-то да, ответ прямо противоречит вопросу; который, впрочем, противоречит реальности :)

Comment: Вопрос ничему не противоречит - это рацпредложение, с реализацией которого пока имеются некоторые технические непонятки.

Comment: Разве? Мне казалось, что автоудаление затрагивает только вариант "более не является необходимым". Собственно это же указано в заголовке.

Comment: @alexolut самолично на это угодил, Николас подтвердил что сработала автоматика. Собственно, ответ написан скорее по просьбе Николаса "собрать заметки в одном месте". У него это и в собственных заметках есть :)

Comment: @D-side Вообще согласен с постом, но в целом (как хорошие обходные пути, "workarounds"), можно сейчас данную тревогу ставить на пост и всё объяснять там или, в крайнем случае, ближайшем "политкорреткном" комментарие, не содержащем "запретных слов".

Answer (score 0):

"Спасибо" и иже с ним - это, да, обратная связь, оценка, мнение и законченность диалога. Это не шум...

И хороший тон еще никто не отменял.

И мы же не роботы... Зачем полностью без эмоций и человеческого? )

Answer (score -2):

Давайте попробуем разобраться в вопросе более детально!

#### Зачем нужны комментарии на сайте?

Если говорить про движок сайта с идеологической точки зрения, то Stack Overflow — это система накопления знаний сообщества, аналогично Википедии. Как и в случае с Википедией, подавляющее большинство посетителей только читают содержимое сайта и никак более не взаимодействуют с системой. Посетителю нужна лишь полезная информация: вопрос, описывающий проблему, и ответы, поясняющеие, как решить проблему. Все остальное — шум. Чем меньше шума, тем тем меньше времени человек потратит на получение нужной ему информации.

Пожалуйста, подумайте:

- Когда в последний раз вы интересовались комментариями, которыми обменивались авторы статьи на Википедии?
- Как часто интересуетесь комментариями после или в процессе прочтения статьи?

Я лично до не знал о существовании обсуждений на Википедии, пока сам не начал писать статью и часть очередной редакции была отклонена, после чего было обсуждение правил проекта.

Если мы выступаем в роли читателей содержимого сайта, необходимость в комментариях резко сходит на нет.

#### Зачем нужны комментарии на сайте?

Комментарии нужны для того, чтобы запросить у автора сообщения дополнительную информацию. Сами комментарии на Stack Overflow (никакие) не должны содержать полезной информации о проблеме или решениях. Вся полезная информация должна быть в ответах и вопросе.

Комментарии — это «кухня» формирования базы знаний, которая должна быть спрятана от посетителя: либо удалена, либо перенесена в чат, с последующим обновлением основного сообщения.

#### Идеология комментариев

Stack Overflow — это сайт *вопросов и ответов*, а комментарии — это сущность второго плана. В идеальном мире люди задают развернутые вопросы с минимальным, самодостаточным, воспроизводимым примером, а авторы ответов им не уступают: публикуют детальные ответы, точно описывающие решения, плюсы и минусы, дополняют ответы кодом и дают ссылки для более глубокого погружения в тему. Как только правильный ответ получен, автор вопроса принимает его и голосует «за». Комментарии в такой системе не нужны... Но мы живем в реальном, а не идеальном мире, где многие авторы сообщений понимают «протокол обмена информацией» в реальной жизни, но отдаленно представляют, что такое Stack Overflow.

ИТ–проекты автоматизируют процессы реальной жизни, а не создают новые, в том числе форумы (речь про форумы, не Stack Overflow). В обычной жизни «протокол обмена» выглядит следующим образом.

- Представьте, у вас сломался компьютер и вы не знаете, как его починить, но у вас есть хороший друг Иван, разбирающийся в компьютерах. (0) Первым делом вы назначаете встречу с Иваном.
- При встрече (1) узнаете, как у него дела.
- В ответ (2) рассказываете про свой быт.
- В удобный для этого момент (3) переходите к вашей проблеме — сломанному ПК.
- Разговор про ПК обычно развивается так:

  - (4) Вы декларируете, что ПК не работает. Делаете паузу.
  - (5) Иван спрашивает у вас, в чем именно заключается проблема.
  - (6) Вы описываете свои наблюдения.
  - (7) Далее идеут пробы ремонта с (8) постоянным запросом дополнительной информации.
- (9) В какой–то момент вы побеждаете проблему, пьете чай с печеньками и расходитесь по домам.

Чтобы помочь людям, которые столкнулись с такой же поломкой, вы публикуете описание проблемы (вопрос) и способы ее решения (ответы) в Интернете. Пожалуйста, скажите, как бы вы структурировали информацию? Вероятно, вы бы собрали все необходимое из пунктов 6, 7 и 8 сжато в вопросе и ответе, а комментарии и уточнения, которые были сделаны в процессе ремонта, а также все остальные шаги, остались бы за кулисами.

Представьте, что мы решаем эту проблему сразу на сайте. Почему в этом случае, после того как мы нашли решение проблемы, нам следует оставлять комментарии? Если в них есть полезная информация, она должна быть перенесена в ответ или в вопрос. Если полезной информации о проблеме или её решениях в комментариях нет, то они должны быть удалены. Все (!), а не содержащие какое–то заданное слово.

#### Автоматизация удаления шума

Подчеркну, комментарии удаляются вручную участниками сообщества, когда они оставляют сигнал тревоги. Автоматизируется процесс проверки тревог, а не удаления.

Стоп–слова были подобраны после анализа уже удаленных комментариев с данной тревогой. Код приложения и данные (удаленные комментарии) [доступны на GitHub](https://github.com/chabanovsky/most-common-in-no-longer-needed). Любой может повторить опыт и посмотреть, какие комментарии соответствуют стоп–словам. Для примере, приведу небольшую часть вывода для стоп–слов.

**Спасибо**

- Очень интересные решения, и ответ великолепный на такой простой вопрос. Спасибо!
- Спасибо, мне помогло :)
- все, сработало, просто добавлял height:auto. спасибо
- @Cheg, спасибо, помогло
- Cheg, всего-то! Спасибо.
- Sultanov Shami спасибо, я новичок в jquery и не знал про функцию each()
- Да сработало, спасибо !
- Александр, великолепно! Спасибо :)
- Спасибо:) Верстаю на bootstrap, поэтому ширина div будет подстраиваться под экраны автоматически:) А края треугольника почему шероховатые такие?
- То, что надо, спасибо!
- Да, это очень близко, спасибо вам, и удачи!
- Спасибо, взаимно)
- …

**Вопрос**

- Не создавайте новых вопрос - не засоряйте форум.
- По прошлому вопросу - Дайте описание TBasicShape.
- Ув. @ZoZexZero, вы слышали про такие замечательные поисковые ресурсы, как Google, Yandex? Они содержат гораздо больше ответов на подобные вопросы, чем может предложить аудитория ХэшКода.
- @wwvv глупый вопрос, говорите? Вы бы тут вопросы по php и JavaScript почитали бы, вот там действительно глупые))
- Повтор вопроса
  [Склонения слов на PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/215279/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php)
  Там кстати можно найти мою попытку упростить читабельность большого текста в котором надо склонить слова при помощи шаблонов.
- @Ольга хорошо что вы пытаетесь разобраться в таких вопросах, это качество поможет вам быстрее освоить js.
- не является ответом на вопрос. пожалуйста читайте вопрос прежде чем публиковать ответ.
- Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/144570)
- А еще лучше - не спамить, исправляя вопрос каждые 5 минут
- Это SO на русском, переведите свой вопрос.
- …

**Ответ**

- Спасибо за ответ @dzhioev
- Спасибо за ответ @Kozlov Sergei
- Огромное спасибо за ответ @Евгений Серебров
- суперответ! зачот!
- @Vladislav  Romarov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).
- Да я над ответом думал ))))). Нашел в справочнике описание как раз подходящее)). Что ж, буду пробовать...
- Обновил ответ
- @dzukp, сделайте ответом. Я приму! Не находил еще подобной информации!
- @Seth, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).
- Жаль 2-х очков репутации не хватает что бы отметить ответ, как только дойду до 15-ти, обязательно отмечу, Спасибо большое!
- Ответ надо галочкой помечать. Я полагаю, что для этого нет репутационных барьеров.
- Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).
- Включите пару примеров в ответ, пожалуйста. Ссылки имеют свойство протухать.
- Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).
- @NicolasChabanovsky , хорошо отметил. А если кто-то даст еще лучше ответ, позже, можно ли его потом отметить как верный ?
- Да, конечно. Для этого нажмите повторно на зеленую галочку (она пропадет) и выберите другой ответ.
- Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как правильный, поставив галку слева от ответа.
- @Grundy да уж, такой объемный ответ выглядит иронично ))
- не является ответом на вопрос. пожалуйста читайте вопрос прежде чем публиковать ответ.
- …

**Код**

- Приведите пример кода, пожалуйста.
- Здравствуйте, хоть по ссылке есть ответ, но ссылка может стать невалидной, поэтому, лучше привести код из нее сюда
- Это не по-питоновски совсем. Ужасный код.
- а обязательно кодировать обратно?
- `но так как я скинул код файла web.php , то надо было искать проблемы в этом файле` - это называется [ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/191482).
- код должен быть текстом. а не картинкой
- Предоставьте код в виде текста, а не картинки
- `setInterval(function() {this.increment()` <- тут this будет уже другой. Так что так код переписывать нельзя. Работать не будет
- прочитать их из файла и положить в ListView. "сарказм". Добавьте код, который вы написали.
- может потрудитесь написать в чем была разница, и можно ли как то еще это написать? а также что bind это люто устарело? и отступы в код добавить заодно
- Почему в тэгах вы указали С#, а код я читаю на С++? Не надо вводить людей в заблуждение
- …

Вероятно, предположения о большом проценте ложного срабатывания несколько преувеличены. Будут новые данные, поменяем стоп–слова или весь подход, если потребуется.

В любой момент мы можем отказаться от автоматизации, переложив проверку на плечи модераторов. Но как бы нам не хотелось, у модераторов тоже будет какой–то процент проверок, [с которыми не все будут согласны](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7046/6). Этого не избежать.

На мой взгляд, нам стоит вернуться к этому вопросу через некоторое время и посмотреть, какие комментарии и *кем* были удалены. Если станет понятно, что надо что–то менять в механизме или стоп–словах,  — поменяем, если увидим намеренное использование системы в корыстных целях — будем бороться с вредительством.

Comment: Про спасибо написал в [другом ответе](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7102/178988). Если кратко - то "спасибо" куда ближе по сути к зелёной галочке, чем к плюсу, поскольку благодарят только за то, что помогло, а не за теоретически красивый ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy Так и есть. Во времена ХэшКода, когда модераторы могли принимать ответы за участников, во время субботников мы по «спасибо» вычисляли правильный ответ, который надо принять.

Comment: Но получается, что оно несёт полезную информацию, а не шум, следовательно, удаляться не должно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Нет, не несет, если ответ принят.

Comment: Это уже дополнительные огоровки, которых в предлагаемом варианте нет. А ещё, помочь решение может не только автору вопроса, так что на "спасибо" можно ставить плюсики.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, но за ответы тоже можно ставить «плюсики», которые еще и в репутацию преобразуются!

Comment: Но одно другому не мешает. Плюс на ответе - это "да, хороший ответ, наверное, должно работать", а плюс на "спасибо, помогло" - это "я тоже использовал этот ответ и он совершенно точно работает".

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, голоса между ответом и комментарием к нему никак не пересекаются, но это не добавляет никакой значимости комментарию. Вопрос не в том, что плохо или хорошо, что можно голосовать за комментарий, а в том, что определенные комментарии не добавляют знаний на сайт, и наоборот, привносят шум.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не касаясь идей шума - меня очень смущает предлагаемых механизм выборки комментариев. Вы вывели список стоп-слов из удаленных комментариев и сделали вывод, что именно эти слова являются маркерами, и что наличие такого слова значительно повышает шанс "проблемности" комментария. Под выборку "код|комментари|вопрос|ответ|спасибо" попадает 27% из вашего тестового списка. Да, это много. Но при этом [под туже самую выборку попадает 25% из неудаленных](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/835744/spasibos)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Т.е. наличие стоп-слова почти не повышает шанс на то, что комментарий - плохой. Эти слова встречаются часто в удаленных комментариях **только потому, что они вообще часто встречаются в комментариях**. А не потому, что они служат надежным маркером потенциального устаревания. По обоснованности - это примерно как разрешить удалять комментарии с буквой "ю" (+- пару процентов).  Взять и разрешить удалять 25% из всех комментариях на сайте - imho, плохая идея. Особенно при наличии потенциальных недовольных таким подходом.

Comment: Вы не учитываете, что комментарии на Википедии скрыты по умолчанию, а тут - показываются. Это их принципиальное отличие!

Comment: @PashaPash Если мы делаем допущение, что сейчас на сайте много комментариев, которы хорошо бы удалить, то высказанное замечание не противоречит интуиции. Идя про повышение шанса мне не понятна, так как мы ничего не можем говорить о не удаленных комментариях, он же не помечены как хорошие. Поясните идею, пожалуйста.

Answer (score -4):

## Почему автоматическое удаление в таком виде или подобном — это очень хорошо

Автоматическое удаление в реализации, где просто ищется вхождение слов — это просто идеально для тех, кто хочет подчищать сайт от лишних комментариев. Чем больше подходящих стоп-слов — тем лучше.

### Такая автоматизация может быть крайне эффективной

[Уже был проведен эксперимент на enSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280546/1548895). Были взяты фразы

```
'%mark%answer%'
'%mark%accept%' 
'%accept%answer%'
'%lease%accept%'
'%mark%answer%'
'%thank%you%'
'%thx%you%'
'%.....'
'+1%'
'-1%'
```

и отмечены флагами несколько тысяч комментариев и точность такой проверки была более 99%. Причём оставшаяся малая дола содержала, как и действительно некорректно отмеченный комментарий, так и явные ошибки модерации.

### Особая позиция модераторов

Этот ответ противоречит [моему другому ответу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7098/220571), но тот ответ больше рассчитан для идеального, на мой взгляд, случая, где модераторы реально пониманиют, что эти комментарии не нужны. Я очень сомневаюсь, что будет так.

Также даже если бы все модераторы были "на моей стороне" то очень не факт, что они бы более точно модерировали комментарии, чем "автоматика". Человеческий фактор всё равно присутствует.

В текущей реализации я просто отмечаю флагом ненужный комментарий и он удаляется. У меня есть разум, чтобы отличать полезный комментарий со стоп-словом и уже неактуальный или изначально бесполезный.

### Ложные срабатывания

Ошибки могут быть — это правда. Но ошибки в модерации комментариев тоже допускаются. И я тут не уверен, чего будет больше ложных срабатываний или ошибок модераторов (ошибочное удаление или неудаление). Для того, чтобы это определить наверняка потребуется эксперимент с чёткими критериями. Иначе это будут голословные утверждения.

### Малое количество пользователей, что-то отмечающее

Я не могу точно знать, как часто комментарии отмечают флагами. Но я полагаю, что это происходит довольно нечасто. Даже форматируют код совсем нечасто в сниппетах, где это делается одной кнопкой.

Поэтому я очень сомневаюсь, что большинство пользователей заморачивается очистой фактажа постов от воды. Отмечают флагами, скорей всего, небольшое количество пользователей, которые хорошо понимают, какие комментарии подлежат удалению. Поэтому предположу, что количество флагов на комментарии, обрабатываемое модераторами, должно быть небольшим. Тут было бы классно, елси бы это модераторы подтвердили или опровергли конкретными цифрами.

### Экономия времени модераторов

[Один из ответов-возражений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7047/220571) содержал один из доводов о том, что у нас не хватает модераторов или времени. Как по мне он некорректен, так для модератора нажатие "принять" или "отклонить" по времени априори не может сильно отличаться. Но мысль о том, что модераторы не справляются с большим количеством тревог просто требует автоматизацию.

Comment: Пожалуйста, предложите оптимальное на ваш взгляд регулярное выражение.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Тут есть много идей как реализовать регулярное выражение. 1. В идеале было бы убрать "автоматику" и провести эксперимент с помощью бота как на enSO. Но с такой позицией модераторов такое не получится. 2. 
Собрать наиболее часто встречающиеся комментарии в регулярку с точными соответствиями на основании SEDE. Мне этот вариант не сильно импонирует, так как остальные тревоги могут активно отклонять. Всё упирается в особую позицию.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Поэтому в текущих реалиях с модераторами, чем больший охват регулярки — тем лучше. Мне нравится ваш текущий вариант. Я уверен, что отмечать флагами всё подряд не будут. Мне гораздо больше верится, что будут отклонять всё подряд.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov **Злостное**, **преднамеренное** расстройство или срыв работы **при соблюдении видимости выполнения её**, скрытое противодействие исполнению, осуществлению чего-н.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov вы постоянно обвиняете модераторов в злонамеренности, саботаже, лицемерии и прочем. пожалуйста, перестаньте разбрасываться необоснованными обвинениями.