# Автоматическое удаление "полезных" комментариев по тревоге

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, комментарии, удаление-комментариев

Насколько я смог убедиться, [автоматическое удаление](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7095/176217) "спасиб" и прочего по стоп-словам совершенно не берёт в расчёт кол-во голосов о "полезности" на удаляемых комментариях.

> [image: пример кнопки установки полезности комментария]

Считаю, что алгоритм автоудаления комментариев по первой тревоге стоит подправить в этом смысле. То есть не удалять такие комментарии автоматически, а отправлять их на проверку модераторам, как это делается для рядовых комментариев, не подпадающих под регулярку.

Список полезных комментариев по ключевым словам можно найти в [запросе SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/revision/912432/1135464/). Рассчитываю на вашу благоразумность :)

Comment: Что такое "полезные голоса на комментариях"?

Comment: @АндрейNOP вот [эти](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMHHb.png).

Comment: Чем они полезны? Если на "Спасибо, я шмогла" будет стоять плюсик, то его не надо удалять?

Comment: @АндрейNOP кто-то решил их отметить "полезными", значит разбираться уже должны люди (модераторы), а не автоматика.

Comment: @АндрейNOP вот выше Ваш комментарий ответили "полезным", он содержит "спасибо". Будь он не на Мете, он мог быть удалён автоматически по первой тревоге.

Comment: Насколько я помню, предложения в последнем посте про автоудаления были проигнорированы. Сие будет и с этим)

Comment: @Suvitruf "мы вам ничего не должны"

Answer (score 1):

Количество голосов на комментарии может говорить о его полезности в какой-то момент в прошлом, но оно ничего не говорит о том, устарел он или нет. Неважно, сколько наплюсовали просьбу перевести вопрос на русский - если вопрос в итоге перевели, комментарий больше не нужен. Голоса на комментариях же нельзя откатить, и комментарии нельзя даже минусовать, поэтому эта характеристика всегда будет искаженным отражением того, насколько актуален комментарий здесь и сейчас.

Я думаю, реальная проблема в том, что идея определять устаревшие (или тем более бесполезные) комментарии только по вхождению подстрок изначально неверна. Регулярное выражение прошло несколько итераций, но все они... не очень хороши. Первый вариант сносил все подряд, а то, что мы имеем сейчас, не учитывает самые популярные устаревшие комментарии типа "обновил ответ", "добавил код" и т.п. Чтобы система работала нормально, она должна учитывать еще как минимум две переменные: длину комментария и его возраст.

Comment: Ничто не вечно... если уж говорить о "полезности в какой-то момент", то можно было бы всё что угодно автоматом удалять по первой тревоге. Я согласен с тем, что система автоматического сноса комментов ещё далека от идеала. Но это не значит, что стоит просто игнорировать такие признаки как "заплюсованность" комментария, лишь на основании того, что он может быть действительно устаревшим и более не нужным. Пусть это решит модератор, а не автоматика. Вопрос лишь об этом, а не о комплексном подходе к автоматическому удалению комментариев. Предлагаю двигаться к решению проблемы постепенно.