# Стоит ли благодарить автора ответа?

Tags: обсуждение, спасибо

В справке есть некоторое несоответствие по этому вопросу.

Например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) сказано, что не надо оставлять "комплименты" (спасибо - это комплимент?).

> [image: Когда не следует оставлять комментарий]

А при наведении на "добавить комментарий" под ответом явно указано, что стоит избегать комментариев типа "Спасибо".

> [image: Подсказка в секции комментария]

Однако в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) разделе справки указано обратное, хотя про комментарии ничего не сказано.

> [image: Как отвечать]

Таким образом, вопрос следующий: стоит ли благодарить автора ответа на вопрос и если да, то где?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Сложности перевода в справке, ну и немного вырван контекст. Стоит взглянуть на [оригинальную статью](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

> Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question. Instead, vote up the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here.

Посыл в том, что «спасибы» признаются, но лучше выражать их в иной форме, например, голосованием.

Comment: Фразу «но это не все, чем вы можете отблагодарить ответившего» определённо стоит куда-то деть

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, плюсанул.

Answer (score 6):

Благодарить можно и нужно, но желательно не в форме комментариев. Лучший способ выражения того, что ответ помог решить проблему - принять этот ответ и добавить +1.

В комментарии тоже можно благодарить, но если это совместить с полезной информацией, которая имеет значение в этом контексте или для будущих читателей - например, Вы можете сказать "Спасибо большое за ответ, я использовал ваш код и добавил вызов вот этой вот функции так как и т.д." или "Ваш ответ очень помог разобраться, что я мог решить это через вот этот модуль" (правда, отдельный ответ может иметь бОльший смысл).

А также, Вы можете запустить "конкурс" (bounty) с причиной "Наградить имеющийся ответ":

[image]

Comment: Могу еще добавить, что благодарности (особенно «спасибо») в комментариях позволяют удалить такой комментарий по первой тревоге без необходимости задействовать модератора. Таким образом, даже длинный и полезный комментарий с маркерными словами может быть легко потерян для сообщества. Я ранее [высказывал позицию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8137/176217), что так, наверное, делать не стоит.

Comment: @älёxölüt ах, да, точно, отличный поинт. Спасибо.

Comment: Тут ещё по вставке картинке [вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320259/responsiveness-breaks-image-proportions#comment1049685_320259) возник.

Comment: @älёxölüt ой, да, она мне по дефолту слишком большой показалась, я пробовал добавлять постфиксы вроде `l`, `m` etc, но ничего не подошло - либо слишком мелким, либо слишком большим казалось. Поэтому пришлось к `img` тэгу обратиться..

Comment: не так давно [суффиксы поломали](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314028/339911)