# Можно ли выражать своё негодование по поводу действий других пользователей?

Tags: поддержка, комментарии, удаление-комментариев

В [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1563379) в комментариях я написал дословно следующее:

> Боже мой, что за токсичность...

И за него даже проголосовали как минимум 2 участника, до того как его удалили - просто информация

За что он был удалён? У нас теперь это считается матом? Или теперь это очень оскорбительные слова?

Могу я выражать своё негодование по поводу действий других пользователей? Или мне нужно обязательно открывать на Мете очередной "полезный" вопрос типа "Сообщество оооооооочень остро отреагировало на бла бла"?

Только не говорите, что он был удалён из-за ненадобности или похожей причины...

Comment: Ни вопроса ни комментария не видел, но тоже бы удалил, просто потому что неинформативно и неконструктивно. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Как обычно, напоминание про то, что SO это не форум и не чатик, это База Знаний. Она куда как больше строится по принципам Вики, чем по принципам Пикабу. Негодованию тут не место.

Comment: @Kromster Ваш троллинг забавляет +1 от меня)) Да я знаю что по правилам тут не место таким вещам, но я думаю что вы согласитесь, что даже вы лично встречали много комментариев, которые к "База Знаний" не относятся, но их никто не удаляет. А тут я даже лично никому не высказался и не оскорблял, но его быстро подчистили. Вот мне и интересно, чем настолько сильно мой комментарий не понравился? Т.е. на мете не раз открывались вопросы такого рода "отреагировали слишком жётско" и т.д., но неужели только так я могу высказаться (открывая вопросы на мете)?

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, троллинга тут нет. Почему все "посторонние" комментарии не удаляются - потому что не хватает рук, да и цели такой нет. Удаляется лишь 1% самого "вызывающего", я бы сказал. Вот ваш комментарий в этот процент попал и был (вероятно) флагнут и удален. В любом случае, негодование площадке не нужно, не тот "формат".

Comment: Вообще странно видеть опытного участника с репой больше 5к, который знает, что посторонние комментарии "не по теме" могут удалять, и тем не менее, хочет найти в этом удалении неприязнь лично к себе.

Comment: @Kromster Я же не сказал, что за мной кто-то специально следит)) Я этот вопрос поднял, потому что несколько раз такое видел, когда чей-то непримечательный комментарий стирают, а когда в комментариях отшучиваются, то за них голосуют и они остаются, особенно, когда переносится в чаты... Просто двоякое поведение какое-то... Но вы правы в целом, раз нельзя, то нельзя... Видимо сегодня просто настроение не то

Comment: Мне кажется, что в целом комментарии не по теме скорее останутся, если они позитивные/добродушные/остроумные/хорошие. Если же это нытье или пассивная аггрессия, или еще что-то подобного рода - их скорее удалят (и правильно сделают, имхо. Жизнь нас итак не радует последнее время, не нужен нам дополнительный негатив).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Комментарии удаляются. Удаляются просто так. Удаляются авторами. Удаляются модераторами. Удаляются, когда перестают быть нужными. Когда кто-то поставил тревогу, шансы, что комментарий будет удалён, увеличиваются. Не стоит ждать, надеяться и верить, что комментарии, которые получили дополнительно голоса "за", будут как-то защищены от удаления. Даже автоматическое удаление не учитывает этот аспект, хотя [было бы неплохо учитывать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8137/176217).

В общем, не стоит искать причину удаления комментария, надо просто быть готовым к тому, что он может быть удалён бесследно (для обычного участника). Если хочется опубликовать что-то более долговечное, стоит начать с сообщения, а не публиковать это комментарием.

Comment: Было бы замечательно ветку дополнить к примеру словом "упоротый" или другие прилагательные о которых в свое время не подумали https://github.com/chabanovsky/flag_words