# В чем смысл "проверки вопроса", если он даже не проверяет лексикон вопроса?

Tags: поддержка, предложение, вопросы

Когда автор пишет вопрос, внизу есть кнопка "Проверить вопрос". Есть ли у этой кнопки хотя бы малейшая функциональность, кроме нахождения почти добуквенных дубликатов?

Например, как был пропущен системой такой вопрос: [Почему импортируемая функция не видит своего тела при обращении к ней ? Я в "self=" Повторно должен указывать путь к функции чтобы оно работало](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1260825/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%af-%d0%b2-sel)? Подсказка: смотреть оригинал без правок, последнее предложение. Цитировать не могу.

Неужели у нашего сайта нет ни малейшей защиты от подобного рода "лексикона"? В русском языке всего 4 матерных корня. Их что, нельзя проверять? Возможно, стоит поднять этот вопрос на оригинальном стеке? Или я что-то не понимаю, и у кнопки есть реальный функционал, а проверки используемых <strike>исконно русских</strike> *нецензурных* оборотов не являются ничьей ответственностью, кроме автора вопроса?

З.Ы. Ну вот [еще](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/913867/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86). Пожалуй, не буду цитировать. Можете прочитать.

Comment: Подстрах\*й, оскорбл\*ть, кол\*баться, ага-ага

Comment: @andreymal А в чем проблема-то? "Употреблять", "обособлять" да много таких. Вот только они допустимы. Недопустимы точные совпадения.

Comment: Я так и не понял смысла этого сообщения. О чем оно вообще? О кнопке (если да, что именно в ней не так?) или нецензурной лексике (а стоит ли о ней вообще волноваться?)

Comment: Вопрос о том, почему сайт при нажатии кнопки "проверить вопрос" не проверяет вопрос на наличие нецензурщины. Если вы считаете, что подобные слова конкретно на этом ресурсе - это норма, то тогда, я думаю, к единому мнению мы все равно не придем.

Answer (score 8):

Мат ­— и что? Если он там нужен, как в другом ответе было сказано, например в вопросе про написании вордфильтра или еще чего — так глупо его не пропускать. (тем более что кому надо — обойдет, был на SE один экземпляр, который умудрялся обфусцировать километровый матюг чтоб не один символ не совпадал, но и его банили) Если он там лишний — пост отредактируют. А если вопрос — просто оскорбление — так его удалят. Бот SmokeDetector сканирует посты на наличие мата и т.д., и даже не только регулярками, но и Perpective API и сообщает о подозрительных постах (правда далеко не идеальнo, но очень неплохо).

Мы не форум с премодерацией (я очень рад, ненавижу такие форумы XD) и уж тем более глупо автоматически не пропускать вопросы из-за мата или чего либо еще.

А кнопка чекает на полные дубли и предлагает автору перечитать вопрос.

Answer (score 6):

Эта кнопка скроллит страницу к началу и предполагает, что автор прочитает написанное и исправит ошибки.

Comment: зачем она тогда вообще нужна? Нормальный человек и так проверит вопрос, как минимум после публикации.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а это вопрос к тем, кто её придумал.

Comment: Я воспринимаю это как то, что мне просто нужно 2 раза вместо одного нажать кнопку Задать вопрос.

Comment: @Эникейщик практика показывает, что проверяют далеко не всегда, и даже кнопка не помогает...

Comment: @andreymal Так я и не говорил, что проверяют всегда.

Comment: @Эникейщик лично у меня складывается ощущение, что проверяют скорее никогда...

Answer (score 4):

Как сказал Qwertiy, у данной кнопки уже есть вполне конкретный функционал.

А я ещё скажу, почему нельзя делать такую автоматическую проверку, какую вы предлагаете.

1. Будут ошибки. Некоторые англоязычные технические термины могут попасть под мат-фильтр и человек не будет понимать, почему его вопрос не пропускается.
2. А если пользователю показывать, из-за каких именно слов его вопрос не пропускают, то он с лёгкостью обойдёт это ограничение *(может использовать латинские буквы x вместо х и y вместо у)*, если желает поматериться.
3. Приведённый вами в качестве примера [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/913867/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86) абсолютно нормален. В нём поставлена реальная практическая задача и требуется решение. То, что вы не считаете нормальным наличиие в нём матных слов - чрезмерное ханжество на мой взгляд.

Иногда мат использовать нормально, когда это обусловлено техническими причинами. Если человек будет просить составить регулярку для матерных слов, тоже не будем его вопрос пропускать? Такая ситуация вполне может быть.

Comment: Автоматическая проверка на матные слова уже существует, но только для комментариев: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5899/

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight хм, ни разу не сталкивался. Но в том, что касается комментариев, такой фильтр имеет смысл.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, она не автоматическая. Должен кто-то прийти и поставить тревогу, а вот дальше уже сработает автоматика. И делалось это не для оскорблений.