# Звезда в чате - то же самое, что и голос на комментарии?

Tags: поддержка, чат, голоса-на-комментариях

**Ситуация:** за комментарий к вопросу/ответу можно проголосовать.
В чатах есть возможность помечать сообщение звездой.

**Вопрос:** звезда в чате - тоже самое, что и голос на комментарии? Или звезда - это нечто большее? Просто как-то раз решил почитать цитатный чат (старые сообщения из него) - и у меня быстро кончились звёзды. Вот я и подумал, что неправильно их использую (слишком часто). Голоса на комментиариях у меня никогда не заканчивались.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

О звёздах в чате можно почитать в [FAQ чата](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) на английском. Чат не локализован, к сожалению.

Сообщение, которое кому-то по какой-то причине понравилось, или просто захотелось его пометить, можно отметить звездой. Можно поставить максимум 20 звёзд в сутки в одной чат-комнате.

Голоса на комментариях иногда воспринимаются как звёзды в чате. Есть даже соответствующее [предложение о превращении апвоутов на комментариях в звёзды](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259469/339911) в чате (когда группа комментариев переносится в чат), но пока оно не реализовано, и не факт, что когда-либо будет.

Comment: Жаль что предложение нет реализовано... Но спасибо, что разъяснили (Ая-яй! Комментарий типа "спасибо" - это плохо!)

Comment: @Зонтик на Мете можно спасибкать. А вот на основном сайте такие комменты даже автоматически удаляются флагами "он больше не нужен".

Comment: Надо же, не знал...

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, `Arigatō` тоже нельзя?

Comment: @avp если в список слов-паразитов внесено, то тоже будет удаляться по упрощённой схеме.

Comment: @Зонтик вот [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5899/176217) почитать можно. Там и список есть весёлый.

Comment: `Arigatō тоже нельзя?` вспоминается старенькая цитата с башорга.