# Почему отклонили тревогу на очевидно недружелюбный комментарий?

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии, тревоги, оскорбление

Поставил тревогу на [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413770/413773#comment415946_413773), но её отклонили. Почему? Очевидно недружелюбно же:

> Не в том месте и не с тем мериться письками пробуете. Мне это не интересно. Я автору дал информацию и вы дали. Какую он посчитает верной путь ту и использует. А все ваше советы, какой-то бред(в прошлом чушь:)) и еще особенно выражение "....поле уникально идентифицирует клиента...". Уникально идентифицирующее поле это поле используемое первичным ключом, уникальное не имеющее повторений значение. Сами то хоть читаете ? и причем тут группировка и уникальное идентифицирующее поле ? А лучший вариант написан в комментарии. И писал лишь рекомендацию основываясь не первом посте вопроса. Зная базу...

Comment: Какого года этот комментарий? И вы не тревогу поставили, а штук 20, за несколько минут. На комментариях 2012-2019 годов. У вас новый парсер? Зачем?

Comment: Если хотите фармить полезные тревоги, делайте это на комментариях с запретными словами, удаляемыми автоматически (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5899/240512), чтобы не увеличивать работу модераторам.

Comment: Кроме быть может самых вопиющих случаев, удаление / перенос в чат комментариев есть вредительство. Моё личное мнение (хотя и весьма непопулярное). Спорить в очередной раз на эту тему нет никакого желания. Но комментарий пишу в надежде, что это хоть как-то поможет вас остановить.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight я и старался так делать, но оказывается некоторые слова не срабатывает.

Comment: @aepot половина из этих комментариев вообще автоматически удалилась. И мне просто стало интересно: а собственно сколько комментариев таких "просматривает" модерация? Поэтому воспользовался этой [хитростью](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6651/532877). В результате нарыл эти 20 комментариев.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight беда в том, что удаление комментариев с запретными словами тоже ломает контекст переписки, я бы выпилил эту фичу полностью...

Comment: @andreymal беда, это когда квалифицированный программист не может научиться выражать свои мысли без запретных слов !!!

Comment: @Dev18 ну учитывая, что одним из запретных слов является "спасибо" - получается, нужно выражать свои мысли в пассивно-агрессивной манере?)

Comment: @andreymal "спасибо" - это не запретное слово как таковое, если коммент его содержит, то не всегда надо его удалять. Речь идёт о недружелюбных комментариях, а не о "спасибах".

Comment: @Зонтик роботу это безразлично, удалит по первой тревоге

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отвечаю на вопрос. Тревогу "враждебный комментарий" отклонил я по слелующим причинам:

- Комментарий не содержит нецензурщины.
- Он старый, и его вероятная недружелюбность уже много лет как ни на кого не влияет.
- Удаление этого комментария сломает контекст переписки, поэтому вместе с ним придётся удалять все остальные связанные комментарии, чтобы не сбивать будущих посетителей с толку. Такое вмешательство модератора очень редко имеет основания. И да, при обработке нескольких из серии ваших тревог, было удалено более одного комментария.

Редактировать этот комментарий я также не нашёл причины. Если бы комментарий был свежий, возможно было бы принято другое решение.

Comment: ...комментарий неприятный, и читать такое случайно (а старые вопросы могут быть прочитанны случайно) на таком сайте, портит привкус сайта !!! //если таких тревог много, то наверно админам можно и прислушаться к мнению большинства.

Comment: @Dev18 мы должны действовать консистентно. В одних и тех же ситуациях принимать одни и те же решения, верно? Я не намерен вычищать десятки тысяч подобных комментариев с этого сайта только но основании вашего отзыва и первой тревоги за последние 8 слет на таком комментарии. Это к слову о большинстве. А так, у нас есть Зонтик, который по дата-майнингу может и 20 таких тревог за 2 вечера выставить, кстати большую часть из них я принял. Если каждый активный участник будет по столько тревог выставлять за 2 вечера, тогда я соглашусь про мнение большинства, но мне придётся покинуть пост модератора.

Comment: Если дело только за прецедентом удаления нехороших слов, я его вам найду: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7140/240512

Comment: @aepot к слову про редактирование. Первое предложение можно было бы и удалить из того комментария раз уж пришло уведомление(правда я не знаю,может это занимает много времени). Оно бы точно смысла не изменило. К слову, мои комментарии регулярно очищались хоть там и не было нецензурных слов.  А что касаемо восьми лет, может и были тревоги в свое время, но иногда людям свойственно не реагировать и возможно "тогда" 8 лет назад не удалили, а мусор если остался в углу, то мало кому охота подчищать, лучше ножкой в угол толкнуть ...я смотрела ссылку нецензурных слов Николая, по ссылке выше

Comment: ...думаю просто это слово не пришло в голову, чтоб включить в список, а так оно попротивней слова "лентяй ...итп"

Comment: @aepot p.s. я бы́ла бы против вашего ухода. (Можете взять паузу, если устали, там по контракту отпусков не дают модераторам???) А вы сайте нужны !!!

Comment: ...и кстати никто не говорит реагировать моментально. Например на англ сайте, если редактируешь вопрос пишут, попробуйте позже очередь занята....если "много" уведомлений и работы может надо что то по типу, пробуйте позже итп,или просто позже посмотреть уведомления. Я не знаю есть ли там тайминг реагирования. Но это точно не причина для ухода, а Зонтик в этом случае очень даже прав=> этот комментарий очевидно не дружелюбный !!!

Comment: @Dev18 "Первое предложение можно было бы и удалить из того комментария". У нас уже были скандалы из-за редактирования комментариев. Пользователям это однозначно не нравится.

Comment: @Nofate пользователям,  которым это не нравится => место в чатиках и форумах...так и передайте им  

Comment: Это информативный сайт и речь не обо мне. //когда я вижу,что кто-то блистает своим красноречием  =>я   знаю,что  там есть  закулисье.... https://www.instagram.com/reel/CezXMlgoTY0/