# Слишком много дополнительных вопросов в комменатриях

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии

Вот в этом вопросе [Как организовать класс с настройками программы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/742209/182162) я дал ответ. На этот ответ в комментариях пользователь задал ещё шесть дополнительных вопросов.

Некоторые ответы могут оказаться очень развёрнутыми, даже более развёрнутым, чем ответ на основной вопрос. Некоторые ответы могут оказаться слишком абстрактными.

Что можно посоветовать пользователю? Задать вопросы отдельно, не в виде комментариев, в соответствии с правилами? Ответить в комментарии на те вопросы, на которые можно дать краткий ответ?

Что можно сделать, чтобы и пользователь оказался удовлетворён, и комментарии использовались как комментарии, а не как вторая площадка для ответов?

Comment: _Что можно посоветовать пользователю? Задать вопросы отдельно._

Comment: @Grundy, синдром ---волчанки--- ответов в комментах? Рекурсивненько вышло :)

Comment: Комментарии, кстати, не от автора вопроса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть замечательный принцип, которым де-факто руководствуются участники сайта в подобных случаях и который [озвучен в идеологическом посте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419/213987) Nicolas Chabanovsky♦:

> [рекомендуется] создавать в одной теме только один вопрос; если в
>   процессе уточнения ответов возникают новые вопросы и эти вопросы
>   *достаточно объемные*, то стоит задать новый вопрос

Comment: В справке данный вопрос не раскрыт, я полистал темы наподобие [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), возможно было неплохо разместить ответ там.

Comment: Я задал вопросы под тем ответом потому что посчитал ответ не полным, то есть охватывающим не все то, что относится к вопросу. Таким образом, в моем понимании, нет смысла в дополнительных отдельных вопросах, так как они никак не дополнят неполный ответ. Кроме того, некоторые мои вопросы касались непосредственно ответа пользователя, то есть спрашивать его о его ответе в отдельном вопросе имхо смысла также не имеет. Ещё мне не ясно, что значит "достаточно объемные"?

Comment: С таким подходом на любой комментарий можно [вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/742209/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B/742241?noredirect=1#comment1136904_742241) отвечать

Comment: @tym32167 Я согласен с вами, что непросто сформулировать в общем случае критерии "достаточности объёмности" и это во многом вопрос вкусовщины. Кому-то хватило бы, кому-то нет... Однако сколько я мониторю вопросы по своим меткам -- вижу, что в большинстве случаев у нас адекватные участники и вполне договариваются под ответом в комментариях, а исключения всегда можно найти, они лишь подтверждают общее правило.

Comment: Если же вам интересно моё мнение по конкретному вопросу, то могу сказать, что тот вопрос уже слишком широкий (запрос на бест практис) и мог бы быть закрыт как too abroad. А в комментариях был запрос на подробнейшую проработку полного спектра ньюансов, которые в разных проектах могли бы по-разному решаться. Также, я в своё время ковырялся в вопросах по этой теме и читал многое со en so -- там это вполне себе отдельные вопросы. А этот наш стиль -- написать в ответе целую книгу не всегда и оправдан.

Comment: Да мне просто не совсем понятно, почему для тех конкретных моих вопросов-комментариев вы рекомендуете создавать новые вопросы? С моей точки зрения в этом смысла нет, так как я просто хотел наводящими вопросами повысить качество ответа.

Comment: @tym32167 Ох, иногда сложно понять, что хотел сказать пишущий и что у него в голове -- сам сталкивался с тем, что пишу вроде понятно, но меня не понимают. [(пример)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40982122#40982122). О том, что вы хотели повысить качество ответа -- на мой взгляд не было видно из написанного вчера. (Ср.: "Плюсую, но КМК можно доработать пост") Ваши интенции видны только в сегодняшних комментариях, а топикстартер ещё со вчера дёргается, на мету пришёл. Но в целом не могу дать совета по тому как строить коммуникации, это вопросы индивидуального стиля участника.

Comment: Ага, ну, я кажется понял. На до было изначально озвучить свои намерения, это помогло бы избежать всей этой канители. Ок, спасибо для разъяснения :)