# Ответы в комментариях

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, комментарии, ответы

большое количество вопросов, ответы на которые написаны в комментариях, при этом вопрос не светится решённым. Я считаю, что писать ответ в комментарии неправильно, это в будущем затруднит поиск решения для аналогичной проблемы. Более того, автор вопроса не может принять ответ в комментариях.

В [обсуждении](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82) от 2015 года чётко сказано:

> Пользуйтесь формой публикации ответа:
>
> ```
> если вы хотите предоставить какую-либо информацию, которая может
> помочь решить обозначенную в вопросе задачу;
> ```

Лично я в таких случаях(как автор), оформляю ответ сам с ссылкой на комментарии. Не знаю насколько это решение верно, но в любом случае оно помогает систематизировать информацию, а тот, кто направил решение в комментарий, добровольно отказался давать ответ.

Считаю, что необходимо обратить внимание на эту проблему и выработать механизм борьбы с ней. Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста конкретизируйте заголовок вопроса, и уточните в чем состоит [meta-tag:предложение]?

Comment: Всё просто: Переносить ответ в ответ и отмечать "общим", либо улучшать и дополнять. [Этот вариант получил наибольшее кол-во голосов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%83-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f/3069#3069). Кстати, сам недавно так сделал.

Comment: В принципе, для изучения истории вопроса, полезно открыть поиск и выбрать все посты с метками https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/комментарии+ответы

Comment: @Kromster так вы же [отвечали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%83-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f/3069#3069) на точно такой же вопрос.

Comment: @Зонтик поэтому и прошу ТС конкретизировать и предлагаю ознакомиться с историей и аспектами схожих вопросов. Возможно ТС имеет ввиду что-то своё или какое-то новое предложение. А то что я оказывается что-то отвечал лет 6-7 назад - я уж и забыл )

Comment: _выработать механизм борьбы с ней_ - механизм состоит из 2 частей: определение и реакция. А всё вместе - правило. Например определение=дубликат вопроса, реакция=закрыть. А здесь что предлагаете? Когда могу, я делаю [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1514402/373567).

Comment: @aepot ну так не совсем хорошо делать. Лучше помечать "общим".

Comment: Ответы в комментах — это нормальность. Иногда лень расписывать в длинный ответ, но одной строчкой можно подсказать что делать. Если оформлять в ответ для получения баллов или из каких-то ещё побуждений, стоит более подробно его расписать. Почему в `using` оборачивать, дать ссылки и т.д. У SO формат википедии, а этот формат не про "*делай так*", а почему надо делать так, ИМХО. Собственно, если просто красть ответ из комментов, минусы легко словить. Если потратить хотя бы 10 минут и постучать по клавиатуре, дать ссылки на документацию и т.д., минусов не словите )

Comment: Боритесь с ветряными мельницами, вместо того, чтобы выявить корень проблемы. Не знаю как другие метки, но C# как по мне скатился, каждый день вижу вопросы низкого качества, где люди не думая хотят сразу решения. Вот когда спрашивают элементарное `2+2=?`, что, писать развернутый ответ прикажете? Я вас умоляю, почти каждый, кто не гонится за рейтингом, ачивками, или чем либо еще (а таких большинство), не напишет ответ, он просто напишет комментарий, либо пройдет мимо. Есть еще те, кто писал в свое время такие ответы, но надоело и перестали. Так может бороться с качеством, а не комментаторами?